# Marcar como pregunta duplicada si está en SO en inglés

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

Por lo que he visto es correcto realizar preguntas ya realizadas de SO en inglés acá en SO en español.

Ya que actualmente mi nivel de inglés no es 100% bueno y las respuestas dadas en SO en inglés no satisfacen mis dudas, hoy realicé la pregunta [Significado de error “connection reset by peer” en conexión TCP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531/significado-de-error-connection-reset-by-peer-en-conexi%C3%B3n-tcp), pero un usuario la marcó como posible duplicada con un link a una pregunta de SO inglés. Entonces me entró la duda si es correcto marcar como duplicada este tipo de preguntas que además en mi opinión no es 100% igual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto va a ocurrir muchas veces, en especial con preguntas simples, y no tiene nada de malo:

1. Un usuario formula una pregunta muy similar a otra existente en el sitio en inglés, *sea de forma intencionada o no*, sin incluir la atribución correspondiente.
2. Otro usuario comenta la existencia de la pregunta original.
3. El usuario que ha formulado la pregunta añade la atribución apropiada; **o bien**, razona que la pregunta es una duda suya legítima y que la coincidencia con la pregunta en inglés es pura casualidad.

Por otro lado, apliquemos el sentido común: para una pregunta tan sencilla como la que mencionas, poco importa que realmente sea una traducción o una duda legítima. El comentario "Posible duplicada de..." debería haber sido más bien "Como referencia, misma pregunta en inglés aquí..."

Comment: Sería genial crear una nueva funcionalidad que permita marcar este tipo de preguntas como "referencia" a otros sitios de SO.

Comment: Dado esto, me surge la duda, ¿Puedo realizar una misma pregunta en SO ingles y en SO español para poder llegar a mas personas con mi pregunta y poder obtener una mejor solución? perdón si esto ya lo habían respondido antes

Comment: @Hector Sí, puedes sin problemas: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/26/23

Comment: @Hector no deberia haber problema alguno, estrictamente hablando son comunidades diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

No es posible marcar una pregunta como duplicado de pregunta en otro sitio.  Solo es posible comentar así.

En el pasado, era común comentar así entre sitios (claro, en inglés), pero ya hace uno dos o tres años, SE decidió que preguntas pueden ser dentro de la temática de sitios múltiples. Entonces, de hecho, nunca, o casi nunca, hace sentido comentar un duplicado entre sitios de lo mismo idioma, tampoco.

El único excepción que puedo recordar es el caso de "cross-posting", cuando una persona pregunta la misma cosa en sitios múltiples (de la misma lengua) **a la misma vez**. Eso es considerado un abuso, y las duplicas deberían ser cerrados.

Entonces, no te preocupes... tu pregunta no es duplica, en el sentido técnico.  El comentario es sólo un comentario.  Y tal vez te puede ayudar con información útil.

Comment: Esto ya se habló aquí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/26/23