# ¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?

Tags: soporte, faq, traducciones-de-contenido, wiki-de-comunidad

> Pregunta original: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/209901)

Algunas preguntas y respuestas están marcadas como *Wiki de comunidad* y son propiedad del usuario [Comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile).

- ¿Por qué tener publicaciones *Wiki de comunidad*?
- ¿Cómo funcionan las publicaciones *Wiki de comunidad*?
- ¿Cómo se convierte una publicación en *Wiki de comunidad*?
- ¿Cómo se puede hacer que una publicación deje de ser *Wiki de comunidad*?
- ¿Las traducciones de publicaciones desde el sitio en inglés deberían convertirse en *Wiki de comunidad*?
- Miscelánea

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 14):

### ¿Por qué tener publicaciones *Wiki de comunidad*?

Uno de los objetivos de este sitio es el de ser una fuente de buena información en constante evolución. Las publicaciones wiki de comunidad ayudan a mejorar el aspecto *wiki* del sitio.

Para más información sobre el uso correcto del wiki, ver [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) y [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

### ¿Cómo funcionan las publicaciones *Wiki de comunidad*?

Las publicaciones wiki de comunidad funcionan mediante la transferencia de parte de la autoría de la publicación del autor original a la comunidad. Hacen que sea más fácil editar y mantener la publicación por parte de un grupo más amplio de personas, pero no contribuyen a la reputación de ningún usuario.

Algunas de las características principales:

- Se necesita una reputación mucho menor (**100** puntos en vez de **2000**) para editar libremente una publicación wiki. <sup>1</sup>
- Los votos en publicaciones wiki (positivos o negativos) no afectan a la reputación de ningún usuario.
- Aceptar una respuesta marcada como wiki [no afecta a la reputación del usuario original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/152859) ni tampoco [da +2 al autor de la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297464).
- Las recompensas otorgadas a respuestas marcadas como wiki otorgan reputación de la manera habitual.
- El autor original recibe medallas por publicaciones wiki según las reglas normales.
- El autor original conserva la reputación ganada (o perdida) antes de que la publicación fuera convertida en wiki.
- El autor original continúa recibiendo notificaciones por ediciones o comentarios en la publicación.
- El usuario mostrado como autor de la publicación no es necesariamente el autor original, es el usuario con [un mayor porcentaje de autoría](http://blog.codinghorror.com/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world/) en la revisión final, determinado por el número de líneas añadidas o borradas, con un bonus (factor de 2) para el autor oiriginal.

### ¿Cómo se convierte una publicación en *Wiki de comunidad*?

Hay tres vías por las que una publicación se puede convertir en wiki de comunidad.

- El autor de **la respuesta** marca la casilla *wiki de comunidad* al redactar o editar la respuesta. Nótese que esta casilla no está disponible para los usuarios nuevos, ni tampoco cuando la pregunta ya es wiki de comunidad. <sup>2</sup>
- Un moderador tiene razones para creer que la publicación sería más útil como wiki de comunidad - si crees que tu publicación [debería ser convertida](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) a wiki de comunidad, puedes [reportarlo para que un moderador le preste atención](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).
- Una respuesta publicada para una pregunta wiki también será wiki. En el pasado las preguntas podían ser convertidas en wiki por sus autores o automáticamente cuando se cumplían ciertas condiciones, pero [ahora la única manera es la intervención de un moderador](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940). Cuando un moderador convierte una pregunta en wiki de comunidad, todas las respuestas existentes se convierten también, y lo mismo ocurrirá con las respuestas publicadas con posterioridad.

### ¿Cómo se puede hacer que una publicación deje de ser *Wiki de comunidad*?

[Un moderador puede hacer que una publicación deje de ser wiki, si es necesario.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373)

### ¿Las traducciones de publicaciones desde el sitio en inglés deberían convertirse en *Wiki de comunidad*?

**No.** O mejor dicho: no, a no ser que la publicación lo merezca por su contenido, con independencia de que sea una traducción o no.

Las traducciones de contenido desde el sitio en inglés [se permiten con mesura](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/236/23); es decir, las traducciones son bienvenidas si son útiles y de calidad, pero se espera que la mayor parte del contenido de nuestro sitio sea creado originalmente por sus usuarios.

Convertir una publicación en wiki sólo porque sea una traducción y supuestamente el autor no merezca la posible reputación devengada tiene dos problemas:

- Se desvirtúa el significado original del wiki, que de forma resumida es "contenido que puede beneficiarse de múltiples ediciones por parte de múltiples usuarios a lo largo del tiempo".
- Si una publicación es útil para la comunidad, no hay razón para que su autor no reciba reputación por ella. [La reputación mide la confianza que tiene la comunidad en un usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), y aportar buenas traducciones es una forma válida de generar confianza.

#### ¿Y si la publicación original ya es wiki?

Aún así, eso **no** significa que la traducción deba ser también wiki. En el pasado, las publicaciones de Stack Overflow se convertían automáticamente a wiki si se cumplían ciertas condiciones (más de diez ediciones por parte del autor original, por ejemplo), pero [dicho mecanismo se suprimió](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/136880); por lo que hay publicaciones que fueron convertidas a wiki sin que realmente tuvieran por qué serlo.

En resumen: que una publicación deba ser wiki o no, no depende del hecho de que sea una traducción.

#### ¿Y qué pasa si se publican traducciones "sin mesura"?

Si detectas que:

- Un usuario ha publicado una traducción sin incluir el correspondiente enlace al original *([ojo, podría no ser intencional](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305/23))*
- Todas o casi todas las publicaciones de un usuario son traducciones
- Hay algún otro problema con una publicación traducida

...entonces deja un comentario para dar una oportunidad de rectificación al autor. Si hay "reincidencia" o para casos especialmente graves, reporta la publicación para que un moderador le eche un vistazo. Esto, intencionadamente, no es más que el mecanismo habitual para tratar publicaciones problemáticas en Stack Overflow.

### Miscelánea

- Las reversiones no pueden usarse para hacer que una publicación deje de ser wiki.
- El usuario Comunidad<sup>3</sup> puede aparecer como el último editor de una pregunta, incluso si no es wiki. Esto ocurre cuando da "empujones" a preguntas antiguas sin respuesta para que atraigan atención.

<sup>1</sup> El autor original de una publicación wiki *siempre* puede editarla, aún teniendo menos de 100 puntos de reputación. Las ediciones realizadas por usuarios con menos de 100 puntos deben ser revisadas de la manera habitual antes de ser aplicadas.

<sup>2</sup> Desde [octubre de 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67582/152859), no hay casilla *wiki de comunidad* disponible para las preguntas.

<sup>3</sup> Ver [Who is the Community User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user), o lee [el perfil del usuario Comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=profile).

*Esta publicación es traducción del original en inglés [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/136880), con el añadido de la sección dedicada a las traducciones.*

Comment: no debería cambiarse a wiki comunitario una publicación si su autor es un miembro activo del sitio y hace el mantenimiento adecuado.

Comment: @rnrneverdies claro, todo eso se tomara en cuenta en cada caso individual