# ¿Queréis ayudar a traducir los privilegios? ¡Hacedlo aquí!

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones, privilegios

probablemente habréis notado que [las descripciones de los privilegios en el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) están aún sin traducir. Son un total de <s>25</s> 23 artículos (*dos ya están traducidos*), un ratito de trabajo, así que cualquier contribución al respecto será bienvenida.

Para facilitar la tarea y disponer de un lugar común donde tener las traducciones, voy a crear una respuesta a esta misma pregunta por cada artículo. Esta respuesta contendrá el texto original del artículo, formateado como código para que todo el markdown quede visible. Quien quiera contribuir con una traducción sólo tiene que <s>crear una respuesta nueva que contenga el contenido copiado de la respuesta original (texto en inglés), y</s> traducir respetando el markdown (*ver "editado" más abajo*). Por supuesto, también podéis usar cualquier editor de texto para crear la traducción y después pegar el resultado en la <s>nueva</s> misma respuesta.

Algunos de los artículos tienen imágenes. Si queréis (¡y sería genial!) podéis sustituirlas por otras que muestren el mismo contenido pero traducido.

¡Muchas gracias por vuestra colaboración!

**Nota:** por favor, al escribir las traducciones usad el tratamiento "tú" (en vez de "usted"), en su día se decidió que lo haríamos así para todas las traducciones de este sitio.

**Editado:** he convertido la pregunta en Wiki para que (casi) todos podáis editar directamente las respuestas. Así pues, por favor añadid las traducciones en la propia respuesta, tras el texto original, en vez de crear una nueva respuesta. Para separar texto original y traducción podéis usar una barra en negrita:

**Editado, la venganza:** Todas las traducciones han sido ya incorporadas al sitio. ¡Muchas gracias a todos los participantes!

```
**----------------------------------**
```

Comment: ¿Y si se ponen como wikis y se mantiene original + traducción en la misma respuesta? Creo que quedaría mejor ordenado

Comment: @Mariano ¡Excelente idea!

Comment: Yo intentare ayudar en lo que pueda!

Comment: @Konamiman sería bueno que dieras algunas traducciones a palabras comunes. Por ejemplo, cómo se traducirá "link"?, "vínculo", "enlace", sin traducción?. Esto porque cada usuario usa alguna alternativa y la idea es que las traducciones se vean consistentes.

Comment: @Lamak creo que estos temas justamente son para ser definidos por la comunidad. Esta es la forma en que podemos moldear la ayuda como mejor nos parezca. Probablemente haya diferencias en las traducciones, pero podemos comentarlas acá, en otra publicación o en el chat. No creo que sea algo para que uno solo lo decida (sin desmerecer Konamiman :-) ... Yo estoy usando *enlace* porque me parece lo más neutro (cuando en el día a día uso *link* normalmente), y se aceptan sugerencias de otros.

Comment: @Mariano es que hay puntos que no necesariamente deben ser definidos por la comunidad y dependen del *estilo* y *forma* en que Stack Exchange quiere comunicarse con sus usuarios. Por ejemplo, Konamiman dice en un comentario que se decidió usar "tú" en vez de "usted". Son cosas que es preferible que sean definidas para que podamos ayudar de forma consistente

Comment: @Lamak Estuve revisando la ayuda, viendo que actualmente se utiliza **enlace** en: [formato](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y se usa **vínculo** en: [reportar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) y [medallas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: @Konamiman Quité el enunciado original para reemplazarlo por el de español... El motivo es que se pueden ver el texto original mirando ediciones anteriores. ¿Está bien o debo dejar el mensaje original junto con la traducción?

Comment: @ArtEze Creo que es mejor dejar el original para que quien quiera revisarlo pueda comparar fácilmente.

Comment: Acabo de comentarlo en Meta de [spanish.se] para que desde allí se ayude también: [¡Ayudemos a traducir la página de privilegios!](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2545/1674)

Comment: He traducido la entrada de [cast close and reopen vote's](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) y me ha surgido una duda. Como podeis ver hay enlaces para aclarar algunos temas que llevan a preguntas del meta en inglés, yo las he dejado tal cual por el momento. Que debemos hacer en estos casos; dejar el enlace a contenido en inglés, eliminarlo, buscar/crear/enlazar con pregunta similar al meta en español, sintetizar y traducir el contenido de la pregunta del meta y añadirlo como información a la traducción...

Comment: @FJSevilla Lo mejor que se pueda. Me encontré con lo mismo y traduje [esta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127) pregunta, pero lleva tiempo y no es algo que uno esté dispuesto a hacer siempre. Se pueden dejar en inglés si no hay una opción en español.

Comment: Qué bien, veo que técnicamente está en [estado-completado] : )

Comment: no se muy bien ingles, puedo ayudar equivocandome?

Comment: No ha llegado pago de mi anterior colaboración. Grr!

Answer (score 2):

**cast close and reopen votes** - traducido

*Help decide whether posts are off-topic or duplicates*

```
### What is closing?

Closing is a democratic voting process where the community identifies questions that duplicate existing content, are unreasonable to answer in their current state, or do not belong on the site.

### When should I vote to close a question?

Questions should be closed by casting close votes if:

 * they are sufficiently similar to existing questions and would be answered identically to them.
 * they are unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem in a way that can be properly addressed by answerers
 * they are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in [the help center](/help/on-topic). 

Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now. See also: [How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?][1]

### How do I cast a close vote on a question?

The current number of close votes will be shown under the question, in parenthesis, like so:

`close (3)`

If there are no close votes, it will simply say:

`close`

To cast a close vote -- or just to view the current count of close votes and reasons -- click the 'close' link under the question body. A list of close reasons, with descriptions and current counts, will appear.

[![Sample close dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO24G.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO24G.png)

If you wish to cast a vote at this point, use the radio buttons to specify a reason for closing the question, then click the "Vote to Close" button. If you select “off-topic”, you will need to select an additional sub-reason explaining why the question is off-topic.

- It takes **$CloseVotesNeededForClosure** close votes to reach the closing threshold (except for duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's current tags, unless that user participated in editing the tags).
- You may cast up to **$CloseVotesPerDay** close votes per day.
- Close votes age away harmlessly if the threshold is not reach after a number of days. If the question has at least 100 views, close votes will age away [after **4** days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594); otherwise close votes will age away [after **14** days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting). Each new close vote resets the timer, so all close votes must be at least 4 or 14 days old respectively before aging occurs.
- You can retract a close vote at any time if the question has not yet been closed by clicking on the 'close' link under the question. This will display the standard close dialog, with the submit button changed to a 'Retract Vote' button.

### What happens when a question is closed?

Once a question has been closed, it will no longer accept new answers and the words `[on hold]` will be appended to the title. After 5 days, if the question remains closed, the word `[closed]` will instead be appended to the title.

Closed questions can be reopened through a similar voting process. The current number of reopen votes will be shown as `current` under the question, in parenthesis, like so:

`reopen (3)`

A tooltip displays the number of votes required to reopen. If there are no reopen votes, it will simply say:

`reopen`

Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may cast at most one close and one reopen vote per question.

Closed questions may be merged with another question, migrated to another site in our network, or even deleted.

### Alternatives to closing

If you don't have enough reputation to cast close votes, or have used up your close votes for the day, there are alternatives:

- If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.
- If the question has serious problems (e.g. it is spam or offensive), [flag it instead][3].


###Reviewing close and reopen votes

This privilege level unlocks two review queues for questions that may need to be [closed][4] or [reopened][5]. 

Any post which currently has an active close vote *or* a close [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) will appear in the Close Votes review queue. In this queue, users can either vote to close the question, edit the question, or recommend leaving it open. Edits or a sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes. If the question receives another close vote after being kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review. Questions with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible duplicate in a tab at the top for easy reviewing.

Similarly, the reopen queue will contain any post that currently has an active reopen vote. Users can vote to reopen, edit the question (which includes a reopen vote), or leave the question closed. A certain number of Leave Closed votes will again kick the question out of the queue and begin the reopen vote aging process, and of course, another reopen vote will put it back into the queue. Questions which get edited within 5 days of being closed will automatically show up in the reopen queue for review. Questions which have had a revision will add an extra tab at the top so that you can quickly view the revision. Like the close votes queue, questions which were closed as duplicates will still list the duplicates in the tabs above.
```

**----------------------------------**

**emisión de votos para cerrar y reabrir**

*Ayudar a decidir si las preguntas están duplicadas o son temas no relacionados*

---

#### ¿Qué es el cierre de preguntas?

El cierre de una pregunta es un proceso de voto democrático donde la comunidad identifica preguntas que duplican el contenido existente, son irrazonables para responder en su estado actual o no son apropiadas para este sitio.

#### ¿Cuándo debería votar para cerrar una pregunta?

Las preguntas deben ser cerradas emitiendo votos de cierre si:

- Son suficientemente similares a preguntas ya existentes y se les respondería de manera idéntica.
- Son poco claras, demasiado amplias o de algún modo hacen difícil identificar el problema de manera que pueda ser abordada por los contestatarios.
- No están relacionadas a la temática del sitio, como se describe en el [Centro de Ayuda](/help/on-topic).

Ten en cuenta que una vez que ganes la reputación necesaria para votar el cierre, no debes reportar las preguntas a un moderador para que sean cerradas o se migren. Ahora es tu responsabilidad votar para ello. Véase también: *[How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?](//meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)*.

#### ¿Cómo puedo emitir un voto de cierre en una pregunta ?

El número actual de votos de cierre se mostrará bajo la pregunta, entre paréntesis, de la siguiente forma:

`cerrar (3)`

Si no hay  votos de cierre, simplemente aparecerá:

`cerrar`

Para emitir un voto de cierre –o simplemente para ver el recuento actual de votos de cierre y sus motivos– haz clic en el enlace 'cerrar' situado debajo del cuerpo de la pregunta. Aparecerá una lista con los motivos de cierre, con sus descripciones y el recuento actual.

[image: Ejemplo de diálogo de cierre]

Si deseas emitir un voto de cierre en este momento, usa el botón de opción para especificar el motivo para cerrar la pregunta, luego haz clic en el botón "Votar para cerrar". Si seleccionas “no relacionado porque...”, necesitarás seleccionar un sub-motivo adicional, explicando por qué la pregunta no está relacionada.

- Son necesarios **$CloseVotesNeededForClosure** votos de cierre para alcanzar el umbral de cierre (a excepción de las preguntas duplicadas, que pueden marcarse como duplicadas con un solo voto de un usuario que ha ganado una medalla de oro en una de las etiquetas actuales de esa pregunta, a menos que el usuario haya participado en la edición de las etiquetas de la pregunta).
- Puedes emitir hasta **$CloseVotesPerDay** votos de cierre por día.
- Los votos de cierre caducan sin tener consecuencias si el umbral no se alcanza después de varios días. Si la pregunta tiene por lo menos 100 visitas, los votos de cierre caducarán [después de **4** días](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594)); en caso contrario, los votos de cierre caducarán [después de **14** días](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting). Cada nuevo voto de cierre restablece el temporizador, por lo que todos los votos de cierre deben tener al menos 4 o 14 días de antigüedad, respectivamente, antes de que se produzca su caducidad.
- Puedes retirar una votación de cierre en cualquier momento si la pregunta aún no ha sido cerrada haciendo clic en el enlace 'cerrar' debajo de la pregunta. Esto mostrará el cuadro de diálogo de cierre estándar, con el botón de envío cambiado a un botón de "Retirar el voto de cierre".

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando una pregunta es cerrada?

Una vez que una pregunta es cerrada, no aceptará nuevas respuestas y las palabras `[en espera]` serán añadidas al título. Después de 5 días, si la pregunta se mantiene cerrada, la palabra `[cerrada]` se añadirá al título en su lugar.

Las preguntas cerradas pueden ser reabiertas mediante un proceso de voto similar. El número actual de votos de reapertura será mostrado debajo de la pregunta, entre paréntesis, de la siguiente forma:

`reabrir(3)`

Una descripción emergente mostrará el número de votos requeridos para reabrir.  Si no hay ningún voto de reapertura, simplemente aparecerá:

`reabrir`

Las preguntas pueden pasar por varios ciclos de cierre y reapertura, pero cada usuario individual puede emitir como máximo un voto de cierre y otro de reapertura por pregunta.

Las preguntas cerradas pueden combinarse con otra pregunta, migrarse a otro sitio de nuestra red o incluso eliminarse.

#### Alternativas al cierre

Si no tienes suficiente reputación para emitir votos de cierre, o has usado todos tus votos de cierre diarios, hay otras alternativas:

- Si la pregunta es duplicada, escribe un comentario con el enlace a la pregunta original.
- Si la pregunta tiene problemas serios (por ej. es spam u ofensiva), [repórtala en su lugar](/help/privileges/flag-posts).

#### Revisar votos de cierre y reapertura

Este nivel de privilegios desbloquea dos colas de revisión para preguntas que pueden necesitar ser [cerradas](/review/close) o [reabiertas](/review/reopen).

Cualquier publicación que tenga actualmente un voto de cierre activo *o* un [reporte](/help/privileges/flag-posts) de cierre aparecerá en la cola de revisión Votos de cierre. En esta cola, los usuarios pueden votar para cerrar la pregunta, editarla o recomendar dejarla abierta. Ediciones o un número suficiente de mensajes "Dejar abierta" la sacarán de la cola de revisión y comenzará de inmediato la caducidad de los votos de cierre. Si la pregunta recibe otro voto de cierre después de salir de revisión, volverá a entrar en la cola para su posterior revisión. Las preguntas con votos de cierre por ser duplicadas también enumerarán cada duplicado posible en una pestaña en la parte superior para facilitar la revisión.

Del mismo modo, la cola de reapertura contendrá cualquier mensaje que tenga actualmente un voto de reapertura activo. Los usuarios pueden votar para reabrir la pregunta, editarla (que incluye un voto de reapertura), o dejarla cerrada. Un cierto número de votos de "Mantener cerrada" volverá a enviar la pregunta fuera de la cola y comenzará el proceso de envejecimiento del voto de reapertura, y por supuesto, otro voto de reapertura volverá a ponerla de nuevo en la cola. Las preguntas que se editan dentro de los 5 días siguientes a su cierre aparecerán automáticamente en la cola de reapertura para su revisión. Las preguntas que han tenido una revisión agregarán una pestaña adicional en la parte superior para que se pueda ver rápidamente la revisión. Al igual que la cola de votos de cierre, las preguntas que se cerraron como duplicados seguirán enumerando los duplicados en las pestañas anteriores.

Answer (score 2):

**create tag synonyms** - traducido

## ::Actualizado::

*Decide which tags have the same meaning as others*

```
### What are tag synonyms?

Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with the correct tags.

### When should I propose a tag synonym?

Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to avoid [manually editing the tags](/help/privileges/edit) on every post by making the retagging *automatic* for common tag mistakes.

### How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?

Users with this privilege and a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

When viewing a tag, look for the box at the top of the page which contains information about the tag with links below it. The last one in that list will be a link to the synonyms page. If there are already synonyms that exist for the tag, the number of synonyms will be shown there as well.

![Finding the synonyms link.][1]

This page will list out all existing synonyms for the tag. Any suggested synonyms for the tag will appear below that with up and down arrows so that eligible users can vote on whether it is valid or invalid. Below that, there is also a box to suggest an additional synonym for that tag.

### How do synonyms get approved?

When a tag synonym reaches a vote score of **4**, it is accepted and becomes active. If a tag synonym reaches a vote score of **-2** it is deleted.

### What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?

Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.

This also increments a synonym counter, which you can view at [/tags/synonyms][2] to evaluate the effectiveness (or ineffectiveness) of the synonyms that are in place.
```

**----------------------------------**

**creación de sinónimos de etiqueta**

*Decidir qué etiquetas tienen el mismo significado que otras*

#### ¿Qué son los sinónimos de etiqueta?

Los sinónimos de etiqueta nos permiten corregir etiquetas incorrectas sustituyéndolas por las que sí son correctas.

#### ¿Cuándo debería sugerir un nuevo sińonimo de etiqueta?

Cuando reiteradamente veas preguntas etiquetadas con una etiqueta errónea o incorrecta -o múltiples etiquetas que quieren decir lo mismo- es un buen momento para proponer un sinónimo de etiqueta. El objetivo es evitar tener que [editar manualmente las etiquetas](/help/privileges/edit) en cada publicación, haciendo que este re-etiquetado sea *automático* para errores comunes.

#### ¿Cómo propongo o voto un sinónimo de etiqueta?

Los usuarios con este privilegio y una puntuación total en respuestas (total de votos positivos menos los votos negativos) mayor o igual a 5 en la etiqueta, pueden **sugerir** sinónimos de etiqueta. Los usuarios con una puntuación total en respuestas mayor o igual a 5 en la etiqueta pueden **votar** los sinónimos de etiqueta.

Cuando estés mirando una etiqueta, mira el cuadrado en la parte alta de la página que contiene información sobre la etiqueta y enlaces en su parte inferior. El último elemento de esta lista será un enlace a la página de sinónimos. Si ya existen sinónimos para la etiqueta, el número de sinónimos también aparecerá allí.

[image: Extracto de etiqueta con el enlace a sinónimos que muestra "sinónimos (1)" para aclarar que ya existe un sinónimo aceptado]

Esta página listará todos los sinónimos existentes para la etiqueta. Los sinónimos sugeridos para la etiqueta aparecerán debajo, con flechas para arriba y para abajo con las que los usuarios que cumplan los requisitos puedan votar si es un sinónimo válido o no.

#### ¿Cómo se aprueban los sinónimos de etiquetas?

Cuando un sinónimo de etiquetas alcanza una puntuación de **4** es aceptada y pasa a estar activo. Un sinónimo de etiqueta es eliminado cuando alcanza una puntuación de **-2**.

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando una pregunta se formula usando un sinónimo?

Cualquier etiqueta que encaje con algún sinónimo de etiqueta activo será automática y silenciosamente sustituida por aquella a la que el sinónimo apunte.

Esto también incrementa un contador de sinónimos, que puedes ver en /tags/synonyms para evaluar cuán efectivos (o inefectivos) son los sinónimos implementados.

Comment: Nótese que la imagen que contiene la publicación está en inglés. Quien tenga un editor de imágenes a mano puede tomar una "foto" de por ejemplo la etiqueta [node]: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs.

Comment: @blonfu ¡gracias por añadir la imagen!

Comment: Eliminé el `::Actualizado::` para que sea tenida en cuenta la edición de @blonfu

Comment: @Juan M nótese que se ha editado la respuesta añadiendo una nueva imagen, esta tomada de [es.so].

Comment: @fedorqui ¡gracias por la aportación!  se ha editado y actualizado el articulo

Answer (score 1):

**create posts - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Ask a question or contribute an answer*

```
### What is asking and answering questions?

The most basic privilege of all -- the right to ask a question, and the right to contribute an answer. This is generally available to everyone, regardless of reputation level.

### When should I ask a question?

Good questions are always welcome, provided you have done your homework first, and can share the results of your research with us.

### When should I answer a question?

Whenever you feel you have something of value to contribute that legitimately answers the question in some way.

Please try to avoid providing "answers" that are

 - requests for help
 - me too!
 - duplicates of existing answers
 - another question entirely
 - requests for clarification from the question asker

Remember, if it's *not* an answer to the posted question, it does not belong among the answers!

### What happens after I ask a question?

When you post a new question, other users will almost immediately see it and try to provide good answers. This often happens in a matter of minutes, so be sure to check back frequently when your question is still new for the best response.

If your question needs clarification, you will see comments in smaller type below your question. If other users ask you for more information in the comments, edit your question using the edit link just below your original question. Providing clarification promptly will help get you the best answers.

As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer. Answers are normally sorted by vote score so the most highly voted answers float to the top. Other users will also vote on the answers to your question.

When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)
```

**----------------------------------**

**publicación de preguntas y respuestas**

*Crear una pregunta o aportar una respuesta*

---

#### ¿Qué es preguntar y responder preguntas?

El privilegio más básico de todos -- el derecho a hacer una pregunta, y el derecho a aportar una respuesta. Esto está generalmente disponible para todos, independientemente del nivel de reputación.

#### ¿Cuándo debo hacer una pregunta?

Las buenas preguntas son siempre bienvenidas, siempre y cuando hayas hecho tu parte primero y puedas compartirnos los resultados de tu investigación.

#### ¿Cuándo debo contestar una pregunta?

Siempre que sientas que tienes algo de valor para contribuir que legítimamente responde la pregunta de alguna manera.

Por favor, evita proporcionar "respuestas" que sean:

- Pedidos de ayuda
- ¡Me pasa lo mismo!
- Duplicados de respuestas existentes.
- Otra pregunta.
- Solicitudes de aclaración de la pregunta.

Recuerda, si **no es** una respuesta a la pregunta publicada, ¡No pertenece entre las respuestas!

#### ¿Qué sucede después de hacer una pregunta?

Cuando publicas una nueva pregunta, otros usuarios la verán casi inmediatamente y tratarán de proporcionar buenas respuestas. Esto sucede a menudo en cuestión de minutos, así que asegúrate de revisar con frecuencia cuando tu pregunta todavía es nueva, buscando la mejor respuesta.

Si tu pregunta necesita aclaración, verás comentarios en un formato más pequeño, debajo de tu pregunta. Si otros usuarios te piden más información en los comentarios, edita tu pregunta usando el botón de edición justo debajo de tu pregunta original. Proporciona la aclaración puntualmente, eso te ayudará a obtener las mejores respuestas.

A medida que veas nuevas respuestas a tu pregunta, vota a favor las útiles haciendo clic en la flecha hacia arriba que se encuentra a la izquierda de la respuesta. Las respuestas se clasifican normalmente por la puntuación de voto, por lo que las respuestas más votadas se ubican en la parte superior. Otros usuarios también votarán las respuestas a tu pregunta.

Cuando hayas decidido qué respuesta es la más útil para ti, marca como la respuesta aceptada haciendo clic en la marca de aceptación, a la izquierda de la respuesta.

[image: clic en la marca de verificación para marcarla como aceptada]

Esto le permite a otras personas saber que has recibido una buena respuesta a tu pregunta. Hacer esto es útil porque le demuestra a otras personas que están siendo valoradas por la comunidad (si no lo haces, ¡la gente a menudo te pedirá educadamente que regreses y aceptes respuestas antes que otra de tus preguntas!).

Comment: ¿Se puede agregar una nueva imagen  @Konamiman ? ¿Te parece bien? En este caso, creo que sería útil agregar la imagen del **✔️**. Más aún, teniendo en cuenta que descubrimos que no hay consenso sobre cómo llamar a la marca de verificación/tilde/otras formas de llamarlo que no recuerdo que varían según el país.

Comment: @Mariano Claro que sí, sustituid y añadid imágenes como creáis conveniente.

Answer (score 1):

**participate in meta - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Discuss the site itself: bugs, feedback, and governance*

```
### What is meta?

Meta is our community for discussing the site itself, including bugs, feedback, and governance issues.

### When should I visit meta?

- to provide feedback
- to report a bug
- to suggest changes to the community
- to discuss how the site works

### Where is meta?

There is a link to meta in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher (top left in the header) and under the "help" menu (top right in the header).

Our meta naming convention is standard across all sites. The meta site for this site resides at: 

$MetaUrl

### Why do I need 5 rep to post there?

Your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the parent site. 

You can always *read* meta with no rep at all.

Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community.
```

**----------------------------------**

**participar en meta**

*Discutir el sitio en sí: errores, opiniones y gestión*

---

#### ¿Qué es meta?

Meta es el subdominio en el que se discuten errores, opiniones y temas de gestión.

#### ¿Cuándo debo visitar meta?

- Dar opiniones
- Reportar un error
- Sugerir cambios a la comunidad
- Discutir el funcionamiento del sitio

#### ¿Dónde está meta?

Hay un enlace a meta en el pie de cada página. El enlace también aparece en el menú de sitios de Stack Exchange (arriba a la izquierda) y en el menú de "ayuda" (arriba a la derecha).

La dirección de meta es estándar en todos los sitios. El meta de este sitio reside en:

$MetaUrl

#### ¿Por qué necesito 5 de reputación para publicar en meta?

Tu reputación en meta es la misma que tu reputación en el sitio principal.

Siempre podrás *leer* meta sin necesidad de reputación.

Debido a que permitimos la participación anónima, necesitamos un poco de reputación del sitio principal para evitar el spam y asegurarnos de que meta sea para los miembros activos y comprometidos con la comunidad.

Comment: @ArtEze hice algunos pequeños cambios si querés revisarlos.

Comment: @Mariano Están bien.

Answer (score 1):

**create wiki posts - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Create answers that can be easily edited by most users*

```
### What are Community Wiki posts?

Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not confer any reputation.

### When should I make my answers Community Wiki?

1. When you want to enhance the "wiki" aspect of your post, so that it can be a continually evolving source of good information through repeated editing.

2. When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting affecting the reputation of those participating in it.

### How do Community Wiki posts work?

You can choose to make any answer you own a community wiki by ticking the checkbox under the edit area:

--------------

![New answer screen shot][1]

Moderators can also choose to convert posts into community wiki mode if they feel [it is appropriate][2] for the question or answer, generally after a discussion with the community and affected individuals.  Once a post is made community wiki, that mode can only be removed by a moderator under exceptional circumstances.

Also see *[What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/)* 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXihi.gif
  [2]: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/
```

**----------------------------------**

**crear publicaciones wiki**

*Crear respuestas que puedan ser editadas fácilmente por la mayoría*

---

#### ¿Qué son las publicaciones Wiki de Comunidad?

Las publicaciones Wiki de Comunidad son más fáciles de editar por todos los usuarios, y no confieren reputación.

#### ¿Cuándo debo hacer una respuesta Wiki de Comunidad?

1. Cuando deseas mejorar el aspecto "wiki" de tu publicación, para que pueda ser una fuente de buena información que evoluciona continuamente a través de ediciones sucesivas.
2. Cuando sientas que tu publicación se beneficiaría por una menor preocupación en la votos que influyen en la reputación de los participantes.

#### ¿Cómo funcionan las publicaciones Wiki de Comunidad?

Puedes convertir cualquier respuesta tuya en una Wiki de Comunidad marcando la casilla de verificación debajo del área de edición:

---

[image: Captura de pantalla de nueva respuesta]

Los moderadores también pueden optar por convertir publicaciones en Wikis de Comunidad si consideran que [es apropiado (*en inglés*)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) para la pregunta o respuesta, generalmente después de una discusión con la comunidad y los individuos involucrados. Una vez que una publicación se hace Wiki de Comunidad, ese modo sólo puede ser removido por un moderador en circunstancias excepcionales.

Puedes ver también: *[¿Qué es una publicación “Wiki de Comunidad”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/13558)*

Comment: @ArtEze incluí el texto original en inglés e hice algunos cambios. Fijate si te parecen bien. La edición en las primeras dos líneas fue principalmente para hacerlas más cortas sabiendo que aparecen en /help/privileges

Comment: @Mariano Perfecto... Ahora voy a hacer lo mismo con mis otras dos traducciones.

Answer (score 1):

**remove new user restrictions** - traducida

## ::Actualizado::

*Post more links, answer protected questions*

```
### What are the new user restrictions?

New users cannot:

- post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile
- contribute answers to protected questions
- ask or answer questions too rapidly

### Why are restrictions placed on new users?

Because we allow participation from anonymous internet users, we must take some precautions to ensure that the rare malicious or spammy anonymous user doesn't ruin the experience for everyone else.

We're sorry that we have to sandbox new users, but the first few upvotes on your questions or answers will quickly elevate you out of it!

### What are protected questions?

High traffic questions on the site may be protected to prevent "thanks", "me too!", and spam answers from new users.

Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. The association bonus does not count.

### How do I add links to my posts?

We use [Markdown][1] to format posts, so there are a variety of ways of adding links:

- bare urls `http://example.com`
- HTML `<a href="http://example.com">example link</a>`
- Markdown `[example link](http://example.com)`
- the editor toolbar button [![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiCqc.png
```

---

#### ¿Qué son las restricciones de usuario nuevo?

Los usuarios nuevos no pueden:

- Publicar más de dos enlaces a la vez, ya sea en una publicación o en su perfil de usuario.
- Contribuir respuestas a preguntas protegidas.
- Hacer o contestar preguntas rápidamente.

#### ¿Por qué se colocan restricciones en los nuevos usuarios?

Porque permitimos la participación de usuarios anónimos de Internet, hay que tomar algunas precauciones para asegurarse de que los usuarios anónimos raros, maliciosos o spammers, no arruinen la experiencia de todos los demás.

Sentimos tener usuarios nuevos en un entorno limitado, pero los primeros votos positivos sobre sus preguntas o respuestas rápidamente los llevarán fuera del mismo!

#### ¿Qué son las preguntas protegidas?

Preguntas de alto tráfico en el sitio pueden ser protegidas para evitar spam y respuestas como: "gracias", "yo también!" de los nuevos usuarios.

Ten en cuenta que se necesita ganar 10 puntos de reputación en el sitio para poder responder una pregunta protegida. El bono  de asociación no cuenta.

#### ¿Cómo puedo añadir enlaces a mis publicaciones?

Utilizamos Markdown [1](/review) para dar formato a las publicaciones, por lo que hay varias maneras de añadir enlaces:

- URLs limpias `http://example.com`
- HTML `<a href="http://example.com"> Ejemplo de enlace</a>`
- Markdown `[Ejemplo de enlace] (http://example.com)`
- El botón de la barra de herramientas [image: insertar botón de barra de herramientas]

Answer (score 1):

**vote up - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Indicate when questions and answers are useful*

```
### What is voting up?

Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers are most useful and appropriate. 

### When should I vote up?

Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

### How do I vote up?

Click the large up arrow to the left of a post, or the small up arrow to the left of a comment.

You can undo your vote by clicking the same button you used to vote, so click the up arrow to undo an upvote or the down arrow to undo a downvote.  To change a vote from up to down, click the down arrow, and vice versa.  Votes can only be changed for a short period of time, so be careful with those clicks!

### What happens when I vote up?

When you vote up, you are moving that content "up" so it will be seen by more people.

* By default, answers are sorted by number of votes.1 
* Upvotes on a question give the asker **+5** reputation.
* Upvotes on an answer give the answerer **+10** reputation.
* Upvotes on a comment help ensure the comment remains visible when there are many comments on a post, but do not give the author any reputation.
* You can vote **30** times per UTC day, plus **10** more times on questions only.

1Except for the accepted answer, which appears first unless it was written by the asker.

### Badges

There are several badges you can receive for voting:

![Supporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km2qC.png)  
First upvote.

![Suffrage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k796s.png)  
Used 30 votes in a day.
 
![Vox Populi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM8kU.png)  
Used the maximum 40 votes in a day.

![Civic Duty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri9Hj.png)  
Voted 300 or more times.

![Sportsmanship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cplsv.png)  
Upvoted 100 competing answers.
 

![Electorate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ2D5.png)  
Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.
```

**-------------------------------**

**voto positivo**

*Indicar que las preguntas y respuestas son útiles*

#### ¿Qué es un voto positivo?

Dar un voto positivo es como la comunidad indica cuáles son las preguntas y respuestas más útiles y apropiadas.

#### ¿Cuándo debería dar un voto positivo?

Cuando te encuentras una pregunta, respuesta o comentario que piensas que es útil, ¡Vota positivo!

Tienes un número máximo de votos al día, así que vota sabiamente.

#### ¿Cómo doy un voto positivo?

Haz click en la flecha hacia arriba en la parte izquierda de la publicación, o la flecha hacia arriba a la izquierda del comentario.

Puedes deshacer el voto haciendo click en el mismo botón, así que haz click en la flecha hacia arriba para deshacer un voto positivo o haz click en la flecha hacia abajo para deshacer un voto negativo. Para cambiar un voto positivo a negativo, haz click en la flecha hacia abajo y viceversa. Los votos sólo pueden ser cambiados durante un breve periodo de tiempo, ¡así que ten cuidado con esos clicks!

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando doy un voto positivo?

Cuando das un voto positivo, estás "subiendo" ese contenido, y será visto por más personas.

- Por defecto, las respuestas están ordenadas por número de votos.<sup>1</sup>
- Los votos positivos a preguntas dan al que hizo la pregunta **+5** puntos de reputación.
- Los votos positivos a respuestas dan al que respondió **+10** puntos de reputación.
- Los votos positivos en un comentario ayudan a que ese comentario permanezca visible cuando hay muchos comentarios en esa publicación, pero no dan al autor ningún punto de reputación.
- Solo puedes votar  **30** veces por día (UTC), además de **10** veces más, en preguntas.

<sup>1</sup>Excepto para la respuesta aceptada, que aparece la primera salvo que haya sido publicada por el autor de la pregunta.

#### Medallas

Hay varias medallas que puedes recibir por votar:

[image: Apoyador]
Primer voto a favor.

[image: Sufragio]
Utilizar 30 votos en un día.

[image: Vox Pópuli]
Utilizar el máximo de 40 votos en un día.

[image: Obligación civil]
Votar 300 veces o más.

[image: Espíritu deportivo]
Votar a favor de 100 respuestas en preguntas donde una respuesta de tu propiedad tenga una puntuación positiva.

[image: Electorado]
Votar en 600 preguntas y que el 25 % o más del total de votos esté en las preguntas.

Comment: No he cambiado las fotos :/ @konamiman

Comment: @lois6b Tranquilo, ya las cambiará alguien (y si no, yo mismo). Cualquier contribución es bienvenida.

Comment: Sugerencia que creo que mejora la legibilidad: _Dar un voto positivo es como la comunidad ..._ → _Dar un voto positivo es la forma en la que la comunidad ..._

Comment: @ninjalj En vez de agregar sugerencias en los comentarios, te recomiendo **[edit]** la respuesta directamente. Son wikis de comunidad justamente con ese objetivo. Y no te preocupes por herir susceptibilidades -al menos yo no lo hago. Si alguien llegara a estar en desacuerdo con tu edición en favor de la anterior, recién ahí se comentaría.

Answer (score 1):

**flag posts** - traducido

## ::Actualizado::

*Bring content to the attention of the community via flags*

```
### What is flagging?

Flagging is a way of bringing inappropriate content to the attention of the community. The currently implemented flag types are the following:

1. Spam (i.e. undiscriminated bulk advertisement)
2. Rude or abusive
3. Not an answer *(answers only)*
4. Flag to close *(questions only)*
    1. Duplicate question
    2. Off-topic (with sub-reasons)
    3. Unclear what you're asking
    4. Too broad
    5. Primarily opinion-based
5. Very low quality (i.e. no amount of editing can salvage the post) (only new posts scoring 0 or less)
6. in need of moderator intervention

If you are ever confused over which flagging reason to choose, please follow the links below:

* [Usage guide for *spam* and *rude/abusive*][spam-off-faq]
* [Usage guide for *not an answer*][not-ans-faq]
* [Guide to off-topic flags][off-topic-faq]
* [Usage guide for *very low quality*][vlq-faq]
* [Guide to *comment* flags][comment-faq]

### When should I flag?

If anything happens on our site that makes you feel uncomfortable or that, in your opinion, clearly does not belong here, *please* flag it and bring it to our attention! 

### How do I flag?

Click the <kbd>flag</kbd> link under any post and you will see the pop-up dialog pictured below.

> **Question**

> ![Flag dialog for question][flag-q]



> **Answer**

> ![Flag dialog for answer][flag-a]

Hover over a comment and click the flag icon ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh47a.png) to the left and you will see the pop-up dialog pictured below.

> **Comment**

> ![Flag dialog for comment][flag-c]


### What happens when I flag something as *spam* or *abusive*?

The spam and abusive flags are designed to automatically eliminate truly disruptive posts through the collaboration of the community.

* 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page. 
* 6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation.

### What happens when I flag a comment?

In addition to bringing the comment to the attention of the moderators, a sufficient number of flags on a single comment will cause it to be deleted automatically. The number of flags required for deletion varies based on the number of votes on the comment, as well as the content of the comment itself.

### What happens when I flag something as *needs ♦ moderator attention*?

You'll be required to enter a comment clearly explaining what the problem is. After that, these moderator flags go in a special high priority queue visible to all moderators. (Users with the Moderator Tools privilege cannot view these flags.) We take moderator flags quite seriously; rest assured that they are all followed up on!

### Is there any way to remove flags?

If, while your flag is still waiting to be handled, you re-open the flag dialog, you'll be presented with the option to *retract* your pending flag:

![retract flag option][retract-flag]

You cannot raise the same type of flag twice on a post: for example, if you retract a "spam" flag, you won't be able to raise a spam flag *or* an abusive flag in the future. 

Retract flags only when you're sure there's no need for the post to be flagged, or you become convinced that a more serious type of flag is needed. 

###What happens to flags?

Many flags are handled by other members of the site like yourself, who've earned [review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) privileges. Close flags, Not an Answer, and Very Low Quality are primarily handled this way.

Some flags can be handled by the system itself: a sufficient number of Spam, Abusive or comment flags results in immediate action (the deletion of whatever was flagged). 

Moderators may step in to handle flags that aren't handled by ordinary members of the site or the system. 

Finally, flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away: rude/abusive and spam flags expire after 48 hours (and are removed immediately if the post is rolled back to a revision prior to the one which was flagged); close flags expire after between 4-14 days (depending on other votes and views).

You can view the outcome of your past flags at any time by clicking on "helpful flags" in [your profile](/users/current). 

### How many flags do I have?

When you start out, you are allotted **10** flags per day. This number may increase to up to **100** flags per day:

- You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
- You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).


  [spam-off-faq]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035
  [not-ans-faq]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392
  [off-topic-faq]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824
  [vlq-faq]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606
  [comment-faq]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365
  [flag-q]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3yhS.png
  [flag-a]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L97lQ.png
  [flag-c]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExaSU.png
  [mod-tools-priv]: /help/privileges/moderator-tools
  [retract-flag]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aoe2.png
```

---

#### Que es un reporte?

Los reportes son una forma de llamar la atención de la comunidad sobre algún contenido inapropiado. Los tipos de reporte implementados actualmente son los siguientes:

1. Spam (es decir, publicidad indiscriminada)
2. Grosero o abusivo
3. No es una respuesta *(sólo respuestas)*
4. Reporte para cerrar *(sólo preguntas)*

   1. Pregunta duplicada
   2. Fuera de tema (con sub-motivos)
   3. No está claro lo que preguntas
   4. Demasiado amplia
   5. Principalmente basado en opiniones
5. Muy baja calidad (es decir, ninguna cantidad de ediciones puede salvar la publicación) (sólo nuevas publicaciones con puntaje 0 o menos)
6. Necesita la intervención de un moderador

   - Estas opciones no aparecerán en el menú de reportes hasta que se haya ganado una reputación de 50 (la cantidad requerida para comentar).

Si alguna vez estas confundido sobre el que razón para elegir para reportar, por favor sigue los siguientes enlaces:

- [Guía de uso para spam grosero/abusivo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)
- [Guía de uso para no es una respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392)
- [Guía de reporte fuera de tema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824)
- [Guía de uso par muy baja calidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606)
- [Guía para comentar reportes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365)

#### ¿Cuándo debo reportar?

Si pasa algo en nuestro sitio que te hace sentir incómodo o que, en tu opinión, claramente no pertenece aquí, por favor, ¡reporta y llama nuestra atención!

#### ¿Cómo puedo reportar?

Haz clic en el enlace <kbd>reportar</kbd> debajo de cualquier 
**publicación** y verás el cuadro de diálogo emergente que se muestra a continuación.

> [image: Reporte Publicación]

Pase el ratón sobre un **comentario** y haga clic en el icono en forma de bandera [image]a la izquierda y verás el diálogo emergente que se muestra a continuación.

> [image: Reporte Comentario]

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto algo como spam o abusivo?

Los reportes de spam y abusivos están diseñados para eliminar automáticamente las publicaciones realmente perjudiciales a través de la colaboración de la comunidad.

- 3 reportes - la publicación es quitada de la página frontal.
- 6 reportes - la pulicación es bloqueada, borrada, y el propietario pierde 100 puntos de reputación.

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto un comentario?

Además de traer el comentario a la atención de los moderadores, un número suficiente de reportes en un solo comentario hará que se borre automáticamente. El número de indicadores necesarios para su eliminación varía en función del número de votos en el comentario, así como el contenido del comentario en sí.

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto algo como necesita la atención de un ♦moderador?

Se te solicita que introduzcas un comentario explicando claramente cuál es el problema. Después de eso, estos reportes de moderador van a una cola especial de alta prioridad visible a todos los moderadores. (Los usuarios con el privilegio Herramientas de Moderador no pueden ver estos reportes.) Tomamos muy en serio los reportes de moderador; ¡puedes estar seguro de que todos están en seguimiento!

#### ¿Hay alguna manera de quitar reportes?

Si, mientras tu reporte está a la espera de ser manipulado, abre nuevamente el cuadro de diálogo de reporte, se visualizará la opción de retraer el reporte pendiente:

> [image: redactar reporte]

No se puede levantar el mismo tipo de reporte dos veces en una publicación: por ejemplo, si te retractas de un reporte "spam", no serás capaz de levantar un reporte spam o un reporte abusivo en el futuro.

Retractar reportes sólo cuando estés seguro de que no hay necesidad de que la publicación se reporte, o si estas convencido de que se necesita un tipo de reporte más grave.

#### ¿Qué ocurre con los reportes?

Muchos reportes son manejados por otros miembros del sitio, que han ganado el privilegios de revisión. Reportes de cierre, no es una respuesta, y de muy baja calidad se manejan principalmente de esta manera.

Algunos reportes pueden ser manejados por el propio sistema: una cantidad suficiente de reportes tipo spam,  abusivos o en comentarios resultan en una acción inmediata (La eliminación de lo que sea que se reportó).

Los moderadores pueden intervenir para manejar reportes que no son manejados por miembros ordinarios del sitio web o el sistema.

Por último, las banderas que no se procesan en un plazo razonable de tiempo: reportes grosero/abusivos y de spam expiran después de 48 horas (y se retiran de inmediato si el mensaje se revierte a una revisión anterior a la que se encontraba reportada); reportes de cierre expiran después de entre 4-14 días (dependiendo de otros votos y vistas).

Puedes ver el resultado de tus reportes anteriores en cualquier momento haciendo clic en "reportes útiles" en tu perfil.

#### ¿Cuántas reportes tengo?

Cuando comienzas, tienes asignados 10 reportes por día. Este número puede aumentar a un máximo de 100 reportes por día:

- Se obtiene bonificación de reportes por cada 2000 puntos de reputación.
- Se le otorga una bonificación de reportes adicionales cuando se reporta correctamente - una bonificación por cada diez reportes útiles netos (reportes útiles menos reportes rechazados).

Answer (score 1):

**set bounties - traducido**

*Offer some of your reputation as bounty on a question*

```
### What is bounty?

A bounty is a reputation reward you can put on a question to get it more attention for exactly one week. 

### When should I place a bounty?

In order to get good answers, you have to put effort into the question. Edit the question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer the question. This will naturally bump the question and get more people interested in it.

However, if after doing this, you feel a particular question *still* isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help.


### How do I place a bounty?

Place a bounty by clicking on the **start a bounty** button. It is found *below* the question's comment area.

![The 'Start a bounty' interface][1]

Use the drop-down menu to adjust the amount of reputation you are willing to award then click on **Start Bounty**.


### What happens when I place a bounty?

- The question is immediately bumped to the top of the active question list.
- The question gets placed in the home page's [**featured** tab](/?tab=featured) for seven days.
- The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.
- If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

It is your responsibility to award the bounty during the seven-day period or the 24-hour grace period that follows it. You will receive several e-mail and site notifications as the bounty period draws to a close.


### Which questions are eligible?

If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the following applies:

* The question has been asked in the last **48** hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.
* You already have three outstanding bounties. You can only have three open bounties at any one time. To start a bounty on this question, you must award at least one of the previous bounties first.
* The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.

You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.


### How do I award the bounty?

You can award a bounty by clicking on the respective button below the upvote/downvote interface. Note that:

* [Community wiki questions](/help/privileges/community-wiki) are eligible for bounties.
* You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it.
* You can award a bounty on an answer without accepting it.
* You must wait 24 hours before awarding a bounty.
* Awarding a bounty cannot be undone.


### When does a bounty expire?

Bounties expire after seven days. You will receive several notifications a few days before this happens.

If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, *half* the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Please note that once a bounty is started, the reputation is non-refundable under any circumstances.

### What badges are related to bounties?

* Promoter — start a bounty for a question of your own
* Investor — start a bounty for somebody else's question
* Altruist —  manually award a bounty on somebody else's question
* Benefactor — manually award a bounty on a question of your own
```

**----------------------------------**

**ofrecer recompensas**

*Otorgar parte de tu reputación como recompensa en una pregunta*

---

#### ¿Qué es una recompensa?

Una recompensa es un premio de reputación que puedes poner en una pregunta, haciendo que consiga mayor atención durante exactamente una semana.

#### ¿Cuándo debería iniciar una recompensa?

Para poder obtener buenas respuestas, debes hacer un esfuerzo en la pregunta. Edita la pregunta para proporcionar actualizaciones de estado y de progreso. Documenta tus intentos continuos para responder la pregunta. Esto, naturalmente, reactiva a la pregunta y logra que más gente se interese en ella.

Sin embargo, si después de hacer todo lo anterior, sientes que una pregunta en particular *todavía* no está consiguiendo la suficiente atención, o que podría obtener respuestas de mayor calidad, puede ser útil iniciarle una recompensa.

#### ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una recompensa?

Coloca una recompensa haciendo click en el botón de **"iniciar una recompensa"** que se encuentra *debajo* del área de comentarios de la pregunta.

[image: Interfaz 'Iniciar una recompensa' - 1]

Utiliza el menú desplegable para ajustar la cantidad de reputación que deseas otorgar y, a continuación, haz click en **"Siguiente"**.

Te aparecerá un menú, en el que deberás elegir alguna de estas opciones:

[image: Interfaz de recompensa - 2]

Una vez elegida la opción, haz click en **Siguiente**, y te aparecerá un cuadro de diálogo en el que es posible aclarar detalles personalizados:

[image: Interfaz de recompensa - 3]

Por último, haz click en **Iniciar recompensa**. De esta manera, has iniciado tu primera recompensa.

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando ofrezco una recompensa?

- La pregunta inmediatamente aparecerá primera en la lista de preguntas activas.
- La pregunta se colocará en [la pestaña **destacadas**](/?tab=featured) durante **7** días.
- La reputación que utilizas para la recompensa es inmediata e irreversiblemente descontada de tu reputación.
- Si tu nueva reputación te lleva por debajo del requisito de cualquier privilegio, perderás el acceso a esos privilegios.
- Es tu responsabilidad adjudicar la recompensa durante el período de siete días, o el período de gracia de 24 horas que le sigue. Recibirás varias notificaciones por correo electrónico y en el sitio a medida que el período de la recompensa llegue a su fin.

#### ¿Qué preguntas son elegibles?

Si no ves el botón de recompensa en una pregunta, se debe a uno o más de los siguientes motivos:

- La pregunta se ha hecho en las últimas **48** horas. Permítele a la comunidad la oportunidad que primero puedan respondan la pregunta.
- Ya tienes tres recompensas pendientes. Sólo puedes tener tres recompensas al mismo tiempo. Para iniciar una recompensa en esta pregunta, primero debes otorgar al menos una de las recompensas anteriores.
- La pregunta ya tiene una recompensa. Para iniciar una segunda recompensa en esta pregunta, primero debes esperar a que la recompensa actual sea otorgada.

No necesitas ser el autor de la pregunta para ofrecer una recompensa en ella.

#### ¿Cómo otorgar una recompensa?

Puedes otorgar una recompensa haciendo click en el botón correspondiente debajo de la interfaz de votos positivos y negativos de la respuesta. Ten en cuenta que:

- Las [preguntas Wiki de comunidad](/help/privileges/community-wiki) son elegibles para recompensas.
- Puedes aceptar una respuesta sin otorgarle una recompensa.
- Puedes otorgar una recompensa en una respuesta sin aceptarla.
- Debes esperar 24 horas luego de ofrecer una recompensa para poder otorgarla.
- Una recompensa no se puede deshacer.

#### ¿Cuándo expira una recompensa?

Las recompensas expiran después de siete días. Recibirás varias notificaciones unos días antes de que esto suceda.

Si no otorgas la recompensa dentro de las 24 horas posteriores a la finalización del período de la recompensa, se asignará automáticamente *la mitad* del valor de la recompensa a la respuesta con más votos que haya sido publicada después del inicio de la recompensa, siempre que tenga una puntuación mínima de 2. Si no hay una respuesta que cumpla estos requisitos, no te otorgará reputación alguna, y la reputación utilizada en la recompensa se perderá para siempre.

Ten en cuenta que una vez que una recompensa se inicia, la reputación no es reembolsable bajo ninguna circunstancia.

#### ¿Qué medallas puedo obtener con recompensas?

[image: Medalla Promotor]
Primera recompensa que ofreces en tu propia pregunta

[image: Medalla Benefactor]
Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en tu propia pregunta.

[image: Medalla Inversor]
Primera recompensa que ofreces en la pregunta de otra persona.

[image: Medalla Altruista]
Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en la pregunta de otra persona.

Answer (score 1):

**create chat rooms - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Create new chat rooms*

```
### What are chat rooms?

Each chat room defines a specific topic; the conversation in that room is expected to loosely follow the topic. Chat typically has a few established rooms for common topics. 

### When should I create a new chat room?

 When you find yourself wanting to have an extended conversation about a topic that is *not* covered by one of the existing chat rooms, you should create a new room for it.

### How do I create a new chat room?

There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper left corner of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.

### What happens when I create a new room?

After you create the room, you'll want to invite other users into your room -- either using the `invite` room menu option, or by pasting the URL to your room as a chat message in other rooms you're participating in.

You can share the chat room URL with the broader internet, but bear in mind that only users who hold the chat privilege on the parent site will be able to *talk* in your room!

### What other new privileges in chat do I get?

At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q652.png
```

**----------------------------------**

**creación de salas de chat**

*Crear nuevas salas de chat*

#### ¿Qué son las salas de chat?

Cada sala de chat define un tema específico; Se espera que la conversación en esa sala siga vagamente el tema. El chat normalmente tiene algunas salas establecidas para temas comunes.

#### ¿Cuándo debo crear una nueva sala de chat?

Cuando te encuentras deseando tener una conversación extendida sobre un tema que no está cubierto por una de las salas de chat existentes, debes crear una nueva sala para el tema.

#### ¿Cómo puedo crear una nueva sala de chat?

Hay un enlace al chat en el pie de cada página. El enlace también aparece en el menu de sitios de Stack Exchange en la esquina superior izquierda de cada página. Haga clic en uno de esos vínculos y, a continuación, haga clic en el botón "crear nueva sala" en la parte inferior de la página Salas.

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando creo una nueva sala?

Después de crear la sala, desearás invitar a otros usuarios a tu sala, ya sea usando la opción de menú de la sala `invitar` o pegando la URL de tu sala como un mensaje de chat en otras salas en las que participes.

Puede compartir la URL de la sala de chat con todo Internet, pero ten en cuenta que sólo los usuarios que tienen el privilegio de chat en el sitio principal podrán *hablar* en tu sala!

#### ¿Qué otros privilegios nuevos en el chat obtengo?

Con 100 de reputación también accedes al botón "Subir imagen" en el chat.

Comment: @Joacer modifiqué "*menú de intercambio*" por "*menú de sitios*" (me pareció que no se entendía). Revisa si estás de acuerdo.

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias por tu corrección, no sabía como traducirlo y puse una traducción bastante literal

Answer (score 1):

**edit community wiki - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Collaborate on the editing and improvement of wiki posts*

```
### What are Community Wiki posts?

Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not confer any reputation. 

### When should I edit Community Wiki posts?

Community wiki posts have been donated to the community in hopes that others will edit them to keep them up to date, to add useful information, and generally improve their quality. 

Take us up on that offer -- whenever you see a community wiki post and have something useful to contribute, *edit it!*

### How do I edit a Community Wiki post?

To edit a Community Wiki post, look at the bottom of the post for the `edit` menu. Also, once you're done editing, provide a brief one sentence summary of your changes in the edit summary field.

### What happens when I edit a Community Wiki post?

All edits are stored in a revision history for the post, along with the author of the revision. Additionally, community wiki posts show the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version in the author field.
```

**----------------------------------**

**edición de Wikis de comunidad**

*Colaborar en el mejoramiento y la edición de publicaciones Wiki*

---

#### ¿Qué son las publicaciones Wiki de comunidad?

Las publicaciones Wiki de comunidad son más fáciles de editar por todos los usuarios y no confieren reputación alguna.

#### ¿Cuándo debo editar las publicaciones Wiki de comunidad?

Las publicaciones Wiki de comunidad se han donado a la comunidad con la esperanza de que otros las editen para mantenerlas al día, agregar información útil y, en general, mejorar su calidad.

Súmate a la propuesta -siempre que veas una publicación Wiki de comunidad y tengas algo útil para contribuir, *¡editalo!*

#### ¿Cómo edito una publicación Wiki de comunidad?

Para editar una publicación Wiki de comunidad, busca en la parte inferior de la misma el enlace a `editar`. Además, una vez que haya terminado de editar, proporciona un breve resumen, de una línea, con tus cambios en el campo resumen de edición.

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando edito una publicación Wiki de comunidad?

Todas las ediciones se almacenan en el historial de revisiones de la publicación, junto con el autor de cada revisión. Además, en el campo autor, debajo de una publicación Wiki de comunidad, se muestra al editor con el mayor porcentaje de texto en la versión actual.

Para mayor información lee: [¿Qué es una publicación “Wiki de comunidad”?](//meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-wiki-de-comunidad)

Comment: @JuanM realicé algunas modificaciones **luego de que hayas actualizado** esta entrada. Me imagino que no es lo deseable pero me parecían cambios importantes.

Comment: Gracias por las modificaciones.  Se han integrado y ya están listos los cambios.

Answer (score 1):

**vote down - traducido**

*Indicate when questions and answers are not useful*

```
### What is voting down?

Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful.

### When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes *cost you a tiny bit of reputation* on top of that; use them wisely.

### How do I vote down?

Click the large down arrows to the left of each post. 

You can undo your votes by clicking the same vote button, but only within a small time limit, so be careful with those clicks.  To change a vote from down to up, click the up arrow without undoing the down-vote, and vice versa.

### What happens when I vote down?

When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.

* Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post owner.
* Downvotes on *answers* remove **1** reputation from you, the voter.
* Downvotes on *questions* are **free**. ([Why?][1])
* You can vote **30** times per UTC day. You get an additional **10** votes on questions only. ([Why?][2])

### What are the alternatives to down-voting?

The [up-vote privilege](/help/privileges/vote-up) comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Instead of voting down:

* If the post is spammy or offensive, [**flag** it](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
* If the question is duplicate or off-topic, [**flag** it for moderator attention](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
* If something is wrong, please [leave a **comment**](/help/privileges/comment) or [**edit** the post](/privileges/edit) to correct it.
```

***voto negativo***

*Indicar si las preguntas y respuestas no son útiles*

---

#### ¿Qué es el voto en contra?

La votación en contra, también conocida como "emisión de votos negativos", es la forma en la que la comunidad indica qué preguntas y respuestas son menos útiles.

#### ¿Cuándo debo votar en contra?

Utiliza tu voto en contra cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás peligrosamente incorrecta.

Tienes un número limitado de votos por día, y además votar en contra en una respuesta te cuesta un poco de reputación. Utiliza estos votos de manera sabia.

#### ¿Cómo puedo votar en contra?

Haz click en **la flecha grande hacia abajo**, que está a la izquierda de cada publicación.

Puedes deshacer tu voto haciendo click en el mismo botón de votación, pero sólo dentro de un límite de tiempo pequeño, así que ten cuidado con esos clicks. Para cambiar un voto de *en contra* a *a favor*, haz clic en **la flecha hacia arriba**, sin necesidad de deshacer el voto hacia abajo, y viceversa.

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando voto en contra?

Cuando votas en contra, estás empujando esa publicación hacia abajo en la página, así que será visto por menos gente. Votar en contra en las publicaciones no es algo que queremos que tomes a la ligera, por lo que no es gratuito.

- Los votos en contra quitan **2** de reputación al dueño de la publicación.
- Los votos en contra te quitan **1** de reputación a ti, el votante.
- Los votos en contra en las preguntas, son **libres**. ([*¿Por qué?*](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))
- Puedes votar **30** veces por día (UTC), además obtienes un adicional de **10** votos solamente para las preguntas. ([*¿Por qué?*](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))

#### ¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto en contra?

El [privilegio de voto positivo](/help/privileges/vote-up) viene primero porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. La reducción de votos debe reservarse para casos extremos. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición.

En vez de votar en contra:

- Si el mensaje es spam u ofensivo, [**repórtalo**](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Si la pregunta es duplicada o no relacionado a la temática del sitio, [**reporta** esto para la atención de un moderador](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Si algo está equivocado, por favor [**añade un comentario**](/help/privileges/comment) o [**edita** la publicación](/help/privileges/edit) para corregirlo.

Answer (score 1):

**create tags** - **traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Add new tags to the site*

```
### What is creating tags?

A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. When you choose to create a new tag, you're asking a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has.

### When should I create new tags?

Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question *does* cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

### How do I create a new tag?

Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...

- must be no longer than 25 characters
- must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

### What happens when a new tag is created?

The new tag will now be available for all other community members to use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in the [moderator tools][1] new tag report.

However, note that:

- on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least **1** other question in a **6** month period.
- meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

Please create new tags responsibly!

[1]: /help/privileges/moderator-tools
```

**----------------------------------**

**creación de etiquetas**

*Agregar nuevas etiquetas al sitio*

---

#### ¿Qué es la creación de etiquetas?

Una etiqueta es una palabra clave o un texto que categoriza la pregunta con otras preguntas similares. Cuando eliges crear una nueva etiqueta, estás haciendo una pregunta en un tema que nadie, antes que tú (en este sitio, al menos), hizo alguna vez.

#### ¿Cuándo debo crear una nueva etiqueta?

Las etiquetas más comunes ya existen en un sitio maduro. Siempre debes favorecer las etiquetas existentes. Sólo crea nuevas etiquetas cuando sientas que puedes argumentar que tu pregunta cubre un nuevo tema que nadie más ha preguntado antes en este sitio.

#### ¿Cómo puedo crear una nueva etiqueta?

Simplemente ingresa una nuevo texto debajo de la pregunta y se creará. Al crear una nueva etiqueta, ten en cuenta que las etiquetas ...

- No deben tener más de 25 caracteres
- Deben utilizar el conjunto de caracteres `a-z` `áéíóúüñ` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando se crea una nueva etiqueta?

La nueva etiqueta estará disponible para que todos los demás miembros de la comunidad puedan usarla, sin necesidad del privilegio de creación de etiquetas. También aparecerá en el reporte de nuevas etiquetas en las [herramientas de moderación](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que:

- En algunos sitios, las nuevas etiquetas se eliminarán automáticamente del sistema si no se utilizan por lo menos en **1** pregunta más en un período de  **6** meses.
- Las meta-etiquetas, aquellas que no tienen valor por sí solas, como la única etiqueta en una pregunta, no se permiten.

¡Crea nuevas etiquetas responsablemente!

Comment: Las frases que comienzan con adverbios no terminan de convencerme. Personalmente, sugeriría los siguientes cambios: _Sólo crea nuevas etiquetas cuando..._ → _Crea nuevas etiquetas sólo cuando..._ _Simplemente ingresa_ → _Basta con que introduzcas_

Answer (score 1):

**view close votes - traducida**

*View and cast close/reopen votes on your own questions*

```
This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions.

### What is closing?

Closing is a democratic voting process where the community defines what is generally on-topic and generally off-topic for this site.

### What is a closed question?

Closed questions do not allow new answers and can be identified by the "(closed)" title suffix. 

It takes **5** close votes from members of the community with the [close vote privilege](/help/privileges/close-questions) to close a question. The reason for question closure is always explained at the bottom. 

### When should I close my own question? 

Questions that are sufficiently off-topic, as outlined in the FAQ, should be closed by casting close votes. Common reasons for question closure are:

- You asked a question that was asked before 
- You asked a question that is off-topic

### How do I view close votes and reasons?

Click on the "close" link under any of your questions, under the question text and to the left side. You will see a list of close reasons, each with a count of the number of votes cast with that reason.

![close vote link with pending close votes, and dialog][1]

You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions.  With the [close/reopen vote privilege](/help/privileges/close-questions), you'll be able to see (and cast) close and reopen votes on all questions.

### What happens to closed questions? 

Some off-topic questions may be migrated to a different site right after closing (we keep the question page with a link to the new location).

Other closed questions may be reopened through a similar voting process.  They can also eventually be merged with another question or even [deleted](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).
```

**----------------------------------**

**visualización de votos de cierre**

*Ver y emitir votos para cerrar/reabrir tus preguntas*

---

Este privilegio te permite ver y emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir tus propias preguntas.

#### ¿Qué es una pregunta cerrada?

El cierre de preguntas es un proceso de votación democrático en el que la comunidad define qué está o no está relacionado con la temática del sitio.

#### ¿Qué es una pregunta cerrada?

Las preguntas cerradas no aceptan nuevas respuestas y pueden ser identificadas por tener el sufijo `[cerrada]` en el título.

Se necesita el voto de **5** miembros de la comunidad con el privilegio de [votos de cierre y reapertura](/help/privileges/close-questions) para cerrar una pregunta. El motivo por el cual se cerró una pregunta aparece siempre al pie de la misma.

#### ¿Cuándo se podría cerrar mi pregunta?

Las preguntas que no están lo suficientemente relacionadas a la temática del sitio, como se explica en la ayuda, deberían ser cerradas por votos de usuarios de la comunidad. Los motivos más habituales son:

- Hiciste una pregunta que ya se había realizado previamente
- Tu pregunta no está relacionada a la temática del sitio

#### ¿Cómo puedo ver los votos de cierre y los motivos?

Cuando una de tus preguntas tiene votos de cierre, puedes hacer click en el enlace a "cerrar", debajo de la pregunta, para ver la lista de motivos de cierre por los cuales han votado, con la cantidad de votos de cada uno.

> [image: enlace a cerrar con votos pendientes y cuadro de diálogo con votos emitidos y motivos]

También puedes emitir votos de cierre o reapertura sobre tus propias preguntas. Cuando obtengas el privilegio de [emisión de votos para cerrar/reabrir](/help/privileges/close-questions), podrás ver (y emitir) votos para cerrar o reabrir *todas* las preguntas.

#### ¿Qué sucede con las preguntas cerradas?

Algunas preguntas cerradas como *no relacionadas* podrían ser migradas a un sitio diferente luego de ser cerradas (se mantiene un enlace desde la dirección de la pregunta a la nueva ubicación).

Otras preguntas cerradas pueden ser reabiertas por un proceso de votación similar. Además, podrían llegar a ser fusionadas con otra pregunta, o incluso [eliminadas](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 1):

**access review queues - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Access first posts and late answers review queues*

```
Review queues (also known as review tasks) contain posts that possibly need community attention, as determined by the system or other community users. You are shown these posts one at a time so that you can evaluate what, if any, action is needed.

The first queues you gain access to are Late Answers and First Posts. These and [all other review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) are accessible from the ["review" link](/review) that appears at the top of every page next to your user name, though you will only be able to perform reviews in the queues open to users of your reputation level.

The **Late Answers** queue contains answers which were posted by new users much later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked, so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same quality standards as all other answers.

 The **First Posts** queue contains the first few posts asked by new users, who may not fully understand the best way to ask and answer questions, or what's on- and off-topic on this site. The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model and to posts that are more likely to need improvement.

In these queues, you can edit the post, flag it, upvote or downvote it, add a comment, or upvote a previously existing comment. When you take one of these actions, the "I'm Done" button becomes enabled, allowing you to complete the review. If you feel that the post is fine as it is, but you don't want to vote on it, click the "No Action Needed" button. If you're unsure about the post, use the "Skip" button to move on to the next review item without taking action on the current one.

Note: These two queues do not exist on [Meta sites](/help/whats-meta).
```

**----------------------------------**

**acceso a las cola de revisión**

*Revisar "Primeras publicaciones" y "Respuestas tardías"*

---

Las colas de revisión (también conocidas como tareas de revisión) contienen publicaciones que posiblemente necesiten atención de la comunidad, según lo determinado por el sistema u otros usuarios de la comunidad. Se te presentarán publicaciones, una por vez, para que puedas evaluar qué acción es necesaria.

Las primeras colas de revisión a las que obtienes acceso son **Respuestas tardías** y **Primeras publicaciones**. Éstas, y [todas las otras colas de revisión](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues), son accesibles desde el [enlace "revisar"](/review) que se encuentra en la parte superior de cada página, junto a tu nombre de usuario, aunque sólo podrás realizar revisiones en las colas en las que tengas acceso según tu nivel de reputación.

La cola de **Respuestas tardías** contiene respuestas que fueron publicadas por nuevos usuarios mucho más tarde que cuando se hizo la pregunta. Las respuestas tardías tienden a ser vistas por menos personas que las respuestas publicadas poco después de la pregunta, por lo que la cola de revisión ayuda a asegurar que estas respuestas cumplan los mismos estándares de calidad que todas las demás respuestas.

La cola de **Primeras publicaciones** contiene las primeras publicaciones realizadas por los usuarios nuevos, quienes pueden no comprender completamente la mejor manera de hacer y responder preguntas, o lo que está en y fuera del alcance del sitio. El propósito de esta cola es prestar atención especialmente a los usuarios que puedan necesitar ser educados en algún aspecto de nuestro modelo y en las publicaciones que tienen más probabilidades de mejorarse.

En estas colas, puedes editar la publicación, reportarla, votarla, añadir un comentario o votar un comentario ya existente. Cuando realices una de estas acciones, el botón "Terminé" se activará, lo que te permitirá completar la revisión. Si crees que el mensaje está bien como está, pero no quieres votar, haz clic en el botón "No se requiere ninguna acción". Si no estás seguro acerca de la publicación, utiliza el botón "Omitir" para pasar al siguiente elemento de revisión sin actuar sobre el actual.

Nota: Estas dos colas no existen en los [sitios Meta](/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Byron hice algunas modificaciones. Por favor revisa si estás de acuerdo y, si te parecen bien, serían para considerar en futuras traducciones.

Answer (score 1):

**established user - traducido**

*You've been around for a while; see vote counts*

```
###What are Established Users?

Established users are those who have been participating on the site for a fair amount of time. They gain the following privileges.

 - They may view the vote counts on posts
 - An expanded usercard will show additional profile information

### How do I view vote counts?

Voting *scores*, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a post. Vote *counts* are the individual up and down votes that make up the score.

You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post. This will break the score into upvotes and downvotes, like so:

![vote count click][1]

The upvotes have a plus sign next to them and are displayed as the top number, in green. The downvotes have a negative sign next to them and are displayed as the bottom number, in red.

### How do people see an expanded usercard?

When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a *hover card*.

![Comparison of normal usercard and expanded usercard][2]

An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.

![Image of drop shadow versus normal][4]

### What information is shown on the expanded usercard?

Your expanded usercard will show the following information:

 - A larger resolution of your **avatar**
 - Your **display name** linked to your profile
 - Your **reputation and badges**
 - Your **Location**, if you have entered one on your profile
 - A **link to your Website**, if you have entered one on your profile
 - Your **About Me** section. Up to the first 298 characters will be displayed as the meat of your expanded usercard. HTML links and linebreaks/paragraphs will be rendered, but not formatting such as bold.
 - Any **additional HTML links** will be displayed and linked at the bottom of the expanded usercard. This does not repeat any links that are already shown in the previous part.

If you don't want the exact text of your About Me section there (such as it is too long and gets cut off, or because the formatting is weird), then you may use a summary comment using the following syntax:

    

Replace `[your text here]` with your desired summary (of at least 28 characters), and that will be placed on your expanded usercard in place of your About Me section. Note that because it is an HTML comment, you cannot use any HTML such as for links. The spaces before and after `summary:` and before the closing `-->` are required to use a summary.

### What if I don't want an expanded usercard to show?

If you have a long profile About Me, but don't want there to be an expanded usercard for any reason, you can use the summary comment with an insufficiently long passage to render your profile as "too short" for display. For example, the following will be considered too short.

    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi9X8.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9wxl.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSPak.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF03C.png
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------**

**usuario establecido**

*Estás por aquí desde hace tiempo; ver recuento de votos*

---

#### ¿Qué son los usuarios establecidos?

Los usuarios establecidos son aquellos que han estado participando en el sitio durante un tiempo considerable. Obtienen los siguientes privilegios:

- Pueden ver el recuento de votos en las publicaciones.
- Una tarjeta de usuario ampliada que mostrará información de perfil adicional.

#### ¿Cómo veo el recuento de votos?

La *puntuación* de votos, tal y como se muestra, es la suma de los votos positivos y negativos de una publicación. El *recuento* de votos son los votos individuales positivos y negativos que componen esa puntuación final.

Puedes ver el recuento de votos haciendo clic en la puntuación de una publicación. Esto dividirá la puntuación en votos positivos y negativos, de la siguiente forma:

[image: Click en número de votos]

Los votos positivos tienen un signo más junto a ellos y se muestran como el número superior, en verde. Los votos negativos tienen un signo negativo al lado de ellos y se muestran como el número inferior, en rojo.

#### ¿Cómo ve la gente una tarjeta de usuario ampliada?

Cuando alguien está viendo tu tarjeta de usuario en una pregunta, una respuesta, o en la lista de usuarios, pueden posicionarse sobre tu avatar para descubrir una tarjeta de usuario ampliada que contiene información adicional. Esto también se conoce como una *tarjeta de usuario flotante*.

[image: Comparación entre tarjeta de usuario normal y ampliada]

La tarjeta de usuario ampliada sólo estará disponible si hay al menos 28 caracteres en la sección "Acerca de mí" en tu perfil. Cuando tu perfil es lo suficientemente largo para generarla, se mostrará un efecto de sombra en tu avatar.

[image: Imagen sombreada versus normal]

#### ¿Qué información se muestra en la tarjeta de usuario ampliada?

Tu tarjeta de usuario ampliada mostrará la siguiente información:

- Una resolución mayor de tu **avatar**
- Tu **nombre para mostrar** vinculado a tu perfil
- Tu **reputación y medallas**
- Tu **ubicación**, si has ingresado una en tu perfil
- Un **enlace a tu sitio web**, si has ingresado uno en tu perfil
- Tu sección **"Acerca de mí"**. Se mostrarán los primeros 298 caracteres dentro de tu tarjeta de usuario ampliada. Los enlaces HTML y las alineaciones/párrafos se mostrarán, pero no se formatearán en negrita.
- Cualquier **enlace HTML adicional** será mostrado y enlazado en la parte inferior de la tarjeta de usuario ampliada. En ningún caso se repetirán los enlaces que ya se muestran en la parte anterior de la tarjeta.

Si no deseas que aparezca el texto exacto de tu sección ‘Acerca de mí’ (por ejemplo, es demasiado largo y se corta, o porque el formato es extraño), puedes utilizar un comentario de resumen con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
<!-- summary: [tu texto aquí] -->
```

Reemplaza `[tu texto aquí]` con el resumen deseado (de al menos 28 caracteres), que se colocará en tu tarjeta de usuario ampliada en lugar de tu sección ’Acerca de mí’. Ten en cuenta que, debido a que es un comentario HTML, no se puede utilizar ningún código HTML, como por ejemplo vínculos. Los espacios antes y después de `summary:` y antes del cierre `-->` se requieren para usar un resumen.

#### ¿Qué pasa si no quiero que se muestre mi tarjeta de usuario ampliada?

Si tienes una sección ‘Acerca de mí’ lo suficientemente extensa, pero no deseas que exista una tarjeta de usuario ampliada por cualquier razón, puedes utilizar el comentario resumido con un pasaje que no sea lo suficientemente extenso, para que tu perfil sea "demasiado corto" para mostrarlo. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente será considerado demasiado corto:

```
<!-- summary: &nbsp; -->
```

Comment: Acabo de traducir esta que quedaba, faltan poner imágenes en español si creeis que son necesarias. He tenido algunas dudas al traducir algunos términos como 'Voting scores', 'vote counts' o 'usercard' que parecen fáciles pero luego surgen la duda de que traducción es más apropiada (al menos a mi...XD). Otros ojos siempre vienen bién en mis textos, soy aficionado a comerme una letra al teclear y luego releo 40 veces y no veo la falta.... [Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) está el enlace a la entrada original en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

**create gallery chat rooms - traducido**

*Create chat rooms where only specific users may talk*

```
### What are gallery chat rooms?

Chat rooms are typically public and open to all. A gallery chat room allows anyone to enter, but only specific users may talk in the room, as determined by the room owner.

### When should I create a gallery chat room?

When you wish to have a controlled conversation between specific community members, without anyone else interjecting.

### How do I create a gallery chat room?

Visit:

$ChatUrl

Click create room, then select the gallery option. Visit the info panel of your room and use the access tab to grant talking privileges to other users.

### What happens when another user enters the room?

They will be able to read the conversation in the room as it happens, but they will not be able to talk until you, as the room owner, grant them the rights to.
```

**----------------------------------**

**creación de salas de chat moderadas**

*Crear una sala de chat en la que sólo puedan hablar determinados usuarios*

---

#### ¿Qué son las salas de chat moderadas?

Las salas de chat generalmente son públicas y abiertas a todos los usuarios. Una sala de chat moderada permite que cualquiera pueda ingresar, pero sólo determinados usuarios puedan hablar (determinados por el dueño de la sala).

#### ¿Cuándo debería crear una sala de chat moderada?

Cuando quieras tener una conversación controlada entre miembros específicos de la comunidad, sin que otras personas intercedan.

#### ¿Cómo puedo crear una sala de chat moderada (gallery)?

Ingresa a:

$ChatUrl

Haz click en "crear una nueva sala", al pie de la página.
[image: botón "create a new chat room"]

Se abrirá el panel de información para la nueva sala, en donde podrás seleccionar `Gallery` para salas moderadas.
[image: Cuadro de diálogo para crear nueva sala con la opción Gallery seleccionada]

Al editar la información de la sala, puedes ir a la pestaña `access` y seleccionar quiénes podrán hablar.

[image: Pestaña access dentro de la página de información de la sala de chat]
[image: Botón para editar permisos de escritura en la sala]

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando otro usuario ingresa a la sala?

Podrán leer todas las conversaciones de la sala, pero no podrán escribir mensajes hasta que tú, como dueño de la sala, les concedas el permiso de escritura

Comment: A falta de un término para `gallery chat rooms`, opté por `salas de chat moderadas`. Si tienen mejor opción, editen.

Answer (score 1):

**approve tag wiki edits** - traducido

## ::Actualizado::

*Approve edits to tag wikis made by regular users*

```
### What are tag wikis?

Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

### Voting on tag wiki edits

All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis. When approving these edits, ensure that: 

- All the content is original or attributed properly 
- Wiki excerpts are concise and contain an objective description of the tag

When you approve tag wiki edits the person submitting the edit will gain 2 reputation points. 

### Finding tag wikis to vote on

Users with the privilege to vote on tag wikis will start seeing them appear randomly between other posts in the [Suggested Edits review task][1]. You can also visit the tag wiki page itself and click on the edit links (similar to a regular post with a suggested edit pending on it) to view the suggestion and vote on it from there.

###What badges can I earn?

For your first tag wiki edit, you get the Tag Editor badge:

![Tag Editor badge][2]

After 50 tag wiki edits, you get the Research Assistant badge:

![Research Assistant badge][3]


  [1]: /review/suggested-edits
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15OaM.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYtMt.png
```

**----------------------------------**

**aprobación de Wikis de etiqueta**

*Aprobar ediciones de Wikis de etiqueta realizadas por otros usuarios*

---

#### ¿Qué son las Wikis de etiqueta?

Las Wikis de etiqueta son una introducción general a la temática de una etiqueta. Es el lugar para formar y consolidar la subcomunidad que se forma alrededor de la misma. Contienen, entre otras cosas, información de cuándo usarla, las preguntas más frecuentes (FAQ), enlaces relevantes, los usuarios principales, y las mejores respuestas recientes de una etiqueta.

#### Votar en una edición de Wiki de etiqueta

Todos los usuarios registrados pueden sugerir ediciones al Wiki de una etiqueta. Al aprobar una edición, asegúrate de que:

- Todo el contenido es original o está debidamente atribuido.
- La orientación de uso (extracto) es concisa y contiene una descripción objetiva de la etiqueta.

Cuando apruebas una edición de Wiki de etiqueta, la persona que haya realizado esa edición obtendrá 2 puntos de reputación.

#### Encontrar ediciones a Wikis de etiqueta para votar

Los usuarios con el privilegio de aprobación de Wikis de etiqueta comenzarán a ver estas ediciones intercaladas con otras publicaciones en la [cola de Ediciones sugeridas](/review/suggested-edits). También, puedes visitar la página de la Wiki de etiqueta y hacer click en el enlace a editar (similar a una sugerencia de edición pendiente de una publicación normal) para ver la sugerencia y poder votar desde allí.

#### ¿Qué medallas puedo ganar?

Por tu primera edición de Wiki de etiqueta, obtienes la medalla Editor de etiquetas:

[image: medalla Editor de etiquetas]

Al editar 50 Wikis de etiqueta, obtienes la medalla Asistente de investigación:

[image: medalla Asistente de investigación]

Answer (score 1):

**access to moderator tools** - traducido

*Access reports, delete questions, review reviews*

```
### What is moderation?

As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example.

You can...

- View deleted posts
- Cast delete and undelete votes on questions
- Access moderator tools
- Edit tags inline

...which collectively allow you to help the elected community moderators in monitoring the site and helping to clean up messes. 

##Viewing deleted posts

You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by moderators, or by the system. 

Use this privilege wisely: 

- Make sure what is being deleted *should have* been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.

- Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion. 

- Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.

You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

## Deleting questions

Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions.

### When should I delete questions?

Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates**; [they can serve as a signpost][1], directing users to useful answers on another question.

It takes **3** votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.

You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users][2] when a post scores **-3** or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please [**flag** it][3] for community moderator attention.

You can view a list of posts with outstanding delete votes via the [moderator tools delete tab][4].

### What happens when a post is deleted?

Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and other fellow users with this privilege. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has **3** undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

### How many times can I vote to delete per day?

At $Privilege-ModerationTools reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day.

## Access moderator tools

You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:

- Posts with extreme votes
- Posts with the most comments/views/edits
- Recently protected questions
- Recently closed/reopened questions
- Recently migrated questions
- Recently deleted/undeleted posts
- Questions with pending close/reopen votes
- Posts with pending delete/undelete votes
- New answers to old questions
- Suggested edit stats
- The full history of reviews by *all* users in any [/review queue](/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

Access these tools by clicking the [review](/review) link in the top bar, and then the Tools link in the header:

![Tools | Review][5]


If you poke around in [/tools](/tools), you'll quickly notice that most of what's found there isn't directly actionable - it's *informational!* What you *do* with that information is up to you: hopefully, you've been around long enough now that you have some idea of how you want the site to be run, and are able to make good use of the information presented. For instance:

- Find problems that've been overlooked and fix them if you can, or bring them to the attention of the moderators if you can't. The [stats page](/tools?tab=stats) is a gold mine for outliers that might benefit from a bit of attention from a wise, aged site veteran such as yourself.

- Find awesome stuff that reminds you of why you like coming here. The stats page is a good one for this too.

- Sanity-check the stuff that other people are doing, and offer guidance and correction where necessary: new tags, new answers, suggested edits, questions being migrated or closed, posts being deleted... Outside of /tools, you also get a full history of actions taken by others in /review by clicking the history tab in any queue, which can be helpful in identifying problems there as well.

Finally, as a high-reputation member of the site your opinions likely carry quite a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to more data makes it easier to back up your assertions. 

##Inline tag editing

Finally, you now have the ability to do inline tag edits on questions. Hover your mouse next to the tags and you should see a "edit tags" button:

![Inline tag edits][6]

This allows you to quickly retag questions that need it, which you'll find especially useful combined with the list of new tags on [the stats page](/tools?tab=stats).
```

**----------------------------------**

**acceso a herramientas de moderación**

*Acceder a reportes, eliminar preguntas, revisar revisiones*

#### ¿Qué es la moderación?

Como uno de nuestros usuarios más experimentados, contamos con que puedas guiar a la comunidad y predicar con el ejemplo.

Puedes:

- Ver publicaciones eliminadas
- Emitir votos para eliminar y recuperar preguntas
- Acceder a herramientas de moderación
- Editar etiquetas en línea

... lo cual, combinado, te permite ayudar a los moderadores elegidos por la comunidad a monitorear el sitio y a limpiarlo de problemas.

### Ver publicaciones eliminadas

Ahora tienes el privilegio de acceder a publicaciones que han sido eliminadas, tanto por sus autores, como por usuarios con acceso a herramientas de moderación, por moderadores, o por el propio sistema.

Utiliza este privilegio con sabiduría:

- Asegúrate de que lo que se eliminó *debería* haber sido eliminado, llevando a la atención de la comunidad y/o del equipo de moderadores cuando han habido eliminaciones innecesarias o dañinas.
- Estate atento a señales de abuso que no son evidentes por haber sido eliminadas.
- No abuses de este privilegio para generar conflicto cuando alguien sabiamente ha decidido eliminar una publicación problemática.

También cuentas con un nuevo operador en las búsquedas para encontrar tus propias publicaciones eliminadas: `deleted:1`.

### Votar para eliminar preguntas

Los usuarios con este nivel de reputación pueden eliminar preguntas que han sido cerradas.

#### ¿Cuándo debería eliminar una pregunta?

Preguntas que han sido cerradas, con contenidos con un valor que no amerite ser mantenido, deberían ser reportadas o eliminadas.

Antes de emitir un voto para eliminar, por favor revisa si hay **alguna respuesta de calidad**. En caso de haberla, entonces la pregunta debería ser reportada a un moderador como candidata potencial a ser fusionada con otra pregunta. ¡No nos gusta perder buenas respuestas!

También, ten cuidado al eliminar preguntas cerradas como **duplicados**, ya que [pueden servir como señalizadores](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), encauzando a los usuarios hacia respuestas útiles en otra pregunta.

Se necesitan, como mínimo, **3** votos para eliminar una pregunta que fue cerrada. No obstante, el número de votos requeridos para eliminarla aumenta según el número de votos que tienen la pregunta y todas sus respuestas.

Debes esperar a que la pregunta haya estado cerrada por **2** días antes de poder emitir un voto para eliminarla. Esta restricción no aplica a [usuarios de confianza](/help/privileges/trusted-user) cuando la publicación tiene un puntaje de **-3** o inferior. Si crees que una publicación debería ser eliminada a pesar de tener muchos votos o de ser nueva, por favor [**repórtala**](/help/privileges/flag-posts) para que sea evaluada por los moderadores de la comunidad.

Puedes ver el listado de publicaciones con mayor número de votos de eliminación en la [pestaña eliminar, dentro de las herramientas de moderación](/tools?tab=delete).

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando una publicación es eliminada?

Una vez que una publicación ha sido eliminada, desaparece para todos los usuarios, exceptuando a desarrolladores, moderadores y a otros usuarios que comparten contigo este privilegio. Sin embargo, las publicaciones eliminadas pueden ser recuperadas emitiendo votos de recuperación. Al llegar a **3** votos de recuperación, dejará de estar eliminada.

Véase también: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](//meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127)

#### ¿Cuántas veces puedo votar para eliminar por día?

Teniendo una reputación con $Privilege-ModerationTools, puedes emitir 5 votos por día. Y se otorga un voto adicional cada 1000 de reputación hasta un máximo de 30 votos de eliminación por día.

### Acceder a herramientas de moderación

A partir de ahora tienes acceso a diferentes listados y reportes estadísticos, los cuales te darán una idea general de la actividad en el sitio:

- Publicaciones con votos extremos
- Publicaciones más comentadas/vistas/editadas
- Preguntas protegidas recientemente
- Preguntas cerradas/reabiertas recientemente
- Preguntas migradas recientemente
- Publicaciones eliminadas/recuperadas recientemente
- Preguntas pendientes de votos de cierre/reapertura
- Publicaciones pendientes de votos de eliminación/recuperación
- Nuevas respuestas para preguntas antiguas
- Estadísticas de edición sugerida
- El historial completo de *todos* los usuarios en cualquier [cola de revisión](/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

Accede a estas herramientas haciendo click en el enlace a [revisar](/review) en la barra superior, y luego en el enlace a Herramientas en el encabezado:

[image: Herramientas | Revisar]

Si revisas las [herramientas](/tools), te darás cuenta de que la mayor parte de lo que contiene no posee botones de acción -¡es plenamente *informativo*! Lo que *haces* con esa información depende de ti: se puede esperar que ya hayas participado lo suficiente como para tener una buena idea de la dirección en la que quieres que vaya el sitio, y que puedas hacer un buen uso de la información que se te presenta. Por ejemplo:

- Encuentra problemas que hayan sido pasados por alto y corrígelos si puedes o, de lo contrario, llévalos a la atención de los moderadores. La [pestaña de estadísticas](/tools?tab=stats) es una mina de oro para encontrar casos atípicos que pueden beneficiarse con un poco de atención y una mirada sabia y experimentada de un veterano del sitio como tú.
- Encuentra material impresionante que te recuerde por qué te gusta estar aquí. La pestaña de estadísticas también sirve para esto.
- Revisa las cosas que otros están haciendo, ofreciendo orientación y correcciones cuando sea necesario: nuevas etiquetas, nuevas respuestas, ediciones sugeridas, preguntas migradas o cerradas, publicaciones eliminadas... Y fuera de las herramientas, puedes ver el historial completo de acciones realizadas por otros en revisión, yendo a la pestaña de historial en cualquiera de las colas, lo cual puede ser muy útil para identificar problemas desde allí también.

Finalmente, como un miembro de la comunidad con reputación alta, tus opiniones probablemente conlleven un peso significativo frente a tus pares: si identificas tendencias que crees que merecen ser remarcadas, no dudes en hacerlo -al tener acceso a más datos, te facilita poder justificar tus afirmaciones.

### Edición de etiquetas en línea

Por último, ahora tienes la capacidad de editar en línea las etiquetas de las preguntas. Pasa el mouse al lado de las etiquetas y verás el botón "editar etiquetas":

[image: Edición de etiquetas en línea]

Esto te permite reetiquetar preguntas de forma rápida, lo cual es sumamente útil en conjunto con el listado de etiquetas nuevas de [la pestaña de estadísticas](/tools?tab=stats).

Answer (score 1):

**trusted user**  -- traducida

## ::Actualizado::

*Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges*

```
### What are trusted users?

Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including: 

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
- Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed  
- Editing tag wikis without needing approval

##Deleting answers
###When should I vote to delete an answer?

You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:

 - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
 - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

## Tag Wikis
### What are tag wikis?

Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.

### When should I edit a tag wiki?

Any time you feel the community around that tag could benefit from an editor's steady hand.

### How do I edit the tag wiki?

All active tags have short description pages, or "tag wikis," at

`/tags/foo/info`

The descriptions include a short summary that is displayed on the main tag page at

`/questions/tagged/foo`

### What happens when the tag wiki is edited?

All tag wiki changes are saved in the revision history, along with the individual editors. You can always view the complete revision history by clicking the `history` link at the bottom of the tag wiki page.

### What should I write in the tag wiki?

See the guidelines in the [blog post announcing tag wikis in their current form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). To summarize:

 * The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
 * Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
 * Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
 * Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.



  [1]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259
  [2]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com
```

**--------------------**

**usuario de confianza**

*Privilegios de edición, eliminación y recuperación ampliados*

#### ¿Qué son los usuarios de confianza?

Los usuarios de confianza pueden realizar acciones de confianza, entre ellas:

- Votar para eliminar respuestas con puntuación de -1 o inferior
- Votar para recuperar respuestas, excepto las eliminadas por un moderador
- Votar para eliminar preguntas con un puntaje de -3 o menos inmediatamente después de ser cerradas
- Edición de Wikis de etiquetas sin necesidad de aprobación

### Eliminar respuestas

#### ¿Cuándo debo votar para borrar una respuesta?

Puedes votar para borrar respuestas en los siguientes casos:

- La respuesta es de muy baja calidad: hay poco o ningún margen de mejora
- La respuesta no intenta responder a la pregunta; Puede ser un comentario o una pregunta por separado.

### Wikis de etiquetas

#### ¿Qué son los Wikis de etiquetas ?

Los Wikis de etiquetas son una introducción general a un tema definido por esa etiqueta. Son un lugar para consolidar y formar una sub-comunidad alrededor de una etiqueta. Contienen, entre otras cosas, las preguntas más frecuentes en la etiqueta, los usuarios principales de la etiqueta y las mejores respuestas recientes en la etiqueta.

#### ¿Cuándo debo editar una Wiki de etiqueta?

Cada vez que sientas que la comunidad alrededor de esa etiqueta podría beneficiarse de una buena edición.

#### ¿Cómo edito la Wiki de etiqueta?

Todas las etiquetas activas tienen páginas de descripción breves o "Wikis de etiquetas" en

`/tags/etiqueta/info`

Las descripciones incluyen un breve resumen que se muestra en la página de la etiqueta principal en

`/questions/tagged/etiqueta`

#### ¿Qué sucede cuando se edita la Wiki de etiqueta?

Todos los cambios en el Wiki de etiqueta se guardan en el historial de revisiones, junto con los editores individuales. Siempre se puede ver el historial completo de revisiones haciendo clic en el enlace `historial` en la parte inferior de la página de información de la etiqueta.

#### ¿Qué debo escribir en la Wiki de etiqueta?

Lee la guía en la [entrada del blog anunciando los wikis de la etiqueta en su forma actual](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) (*en inglés*). En resumen:

- El extracto es el primer contacto de la etiqueta.
- Evita definir genéricamente el concepto detrás de una etiqueta, a menos que esté altamente especializada.
- Concéntrate en lo que significa una etiqueta para su comunidad.
- Proporciona una guía básica sobre cuándo usar la etiqueta.

Comment: @jasilva hice algunas modificaciones intentando que coincida con el resto de las publicaciones (principalmente hablando de "tú"). Revisa si estás de acuerdo.

Comment: Me parece adecuado @Mariano gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

**access to site analytics - traducido**

*Access to internal and Google site analytics*

```
## What are site analytics?

People who run websites use data about how the site is used to make informed decisions. Since our sites are [community run](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/), we give the most engaged users special access to some of the data we collect. Once you earn the privilege, you can visit [/site-analytics](/site-analytics) to explore site statistics in two tabs:

### History

Three graphs show a timeline of posts, votes, and traffic. Date selectors across the top of the page control the range of dates displayed:

[![Timeline controls][1]][1]

Site milestone dates are also provided and, if clicked, will change the start date of the graphs. Selecting the "Weekly" checkbox will change the data points to per week. 

Data series can be toggled via checkboxes to the left of each chart:

[![Data series toggle][2]][2]

Get a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) copy of the displayed data suitable for offline analysis by clicking the "csv" link. Note that unlike most other sources, such as [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), this data includes information on deleted posts.

### Google Analytics

This tab gives you access to select [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) data from the last 30 days. There are a few oddities in the data:

* DuckDuckGo shows up [as a referring site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics) and not a search engine. 

* The numbers are [sampled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/analytics-search-keywords-are-unreliable) so it's not uncommon to see implausible results such as several search engines at exactly 211 visits.

* We have a limited API quota, so arbitrary date ranges are not supported.

* Search terms are so unreliable that we just aren't showing them.

## How should I use this data?

Since this is a restricted privilege, we'd prefer you not share the raw data. However, we _do_ hope you will share your analysis of the data with other users on meta. For instance, mature Stack Exchange sites tend to get the majority of their traffic from search engines (and particularly Google). Sharing the current percentage of traffic from search might shed some light on your site's particular strengths or weaknesses.

Please don't feel any obligation to share this data. (And if you don't yet have the privilege, please don't pressure those who have into sharing.) It's mostly intended as a way to satisfy your own curiosity about the state of the community.
```

**----------------------------------**

**acceso a estadísticas del sitio**

*Acceder a estadísticas internas y de Google Analytics*

---

### ¿Qué son las estadísticas del sitio?

Quienes administran sitios web, analizan información de cómo se utiliza el sitio para tomar decisiones informadas. Nuestros sitios son [gestionados por la propia comunidad](//blog.stackexchange.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/), por lo que a nuestros usuarios más comprometidos les ofrecemos acceso a algunos de los datos que recopilamos. Cuando obtienes este privilegio, puedes ingresar a /site-analytics y explorar las estadísticas del sitio organizadas en dos pestañas:

#### Historial

Tres gráficos que muestran una línea de tiempo de publicaciones, votos y tráfico. Los selectores de fecha en la parte superior de la página filtran el intervalo con el que se muestran:

[image: Selectores de fecha desde - hasta]

También se proporcionan las fechas de inicio del beta y de graduación y, si haces click, cambiarán la fecha de inicio de los gráficos automáticamente. Si seleccionas la casilla de verificación "Semanalmente", se cambiarán los puntos de datos por semanas.

Las series de datos graficadas se pueden alternar mediante casillas de verificación a la izquierda de cada gráfico:

[image: Data series toggle]

Puedes descargar una copia en formato [CSV](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) de los datos graficados para analizarlos con tus propias herramientas haciendo click en el enlace "csv". Ten en cuenta que, a diferencia de otras fuentes de información, como por ejemplo [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com/), estos datos incluyen la información de publicaciones eliminadas.

#### Google Analytics

Esta pestaña te confiere acceso a algunos de los datos recabados por [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) para los últimos 30 días. Los datos tienen algunas peculiaridades:

- DuckDuckGo aparece [como origen (*referrer*)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/258390/304899) y no como un buscador.
- Los números se [muestrean](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/121423/304899), por lo que no es raro ver resultados inverosímiles, como por ejemplo varios motores de búsqueda con exactamente 211 visitas.
- Tenemos una cuota limitada en la API, por lo que no se permiten rangos arbitrarios de fechas.
- Los términos de búsqueda tienen muy baja confiabilidad, por ende no los estamos mostrando.

### ¿Cómo podría usar esta información?

Dado que se trata de un privilegio restringido, preferimos que no compartas los datos en crudo. Sin embargo, esperamos que compartas tus análisis con otros usuarios en meta. Por ejemplo, los sitios más establecidos de Stack Exchange tienden a obtener la mayor parte de su tráfico de los motores de búsqueda (y particularmente de Google). Compartir el porcentaje actual de tráfico desde búsquedas puede ayudar a estudiar las debilidades y fortalezas del sitio.

Por favor, no sientas ninguna obligación en compartir estos datos (y si todavía no tienes el privilegio, no presiones a quienes lo tienen). Están, más que nada, orientados a satisfacer tu propia curiosidad sobre el estado actual de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

**talk in chat - traducido**

## ::Actualizado::

*Participate in this site's chat rooms*

```
### What is chat?

All sites have a real time web chat component, or as we like to call it, the "third place".

> [The third place][1] is a term used in the concept of community building to refer to social surroundings separate from the two usual social environments of home and the workplace. In his influential book The Great Good Place, Ray Oldenburg argues that third places are important for civil society, democracy, civic engagement, and establishing feelings of a sense of place.

> Most needed are those ‘third places’ which lend a public balance to the increased privatization of home life. Third places are nothing more than informal public gathering places. The phrase ‘third places’ derives from considering our homes to be the ‘first’ places in our lives, and our work places the ‘second.’

### When should I visit chat?

- for real time collaboration
- to meet the fellow members of your community in a more social environment
- for less structured, casual (but still roughly on-topic) conversation

### Where is chat?

There is a link to chat in the footer of every page, as well as in the Stack Exchange site switcher menu (top left corner of the page). The chat for this site is at:

$ChatUrl

### Why do I need 20 rep to talk in chat?

Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation on the parent site. 

You can always enter chat rooms and listen with no rep at all.

We can't allow anonymous participation on chat, so we require a small bit of parent site reputation to ensure that chat is reserved for active, engaged members of the community.

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place
```

**----------------------------------**

**Hablar en el chat**

*Participar en las salas de chat de este sitio*

---

#### ¿Qué es un chat?

Todos los sitios tienen un componente web chat en tiempo real, o como nos gusta llamarlo, el "tercer lugar".

> [El tercer lugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) es un término utilizado en la comunidad para referirse al entorno social separado de los dos ambientes sociales habituales, casa y el lugar de trabajo. En su influyente libro *The Great Good Place*, Ray Oldenburg argumenta que los terceros lugares son importantes para la sociedad civil, la democracia, el compromiso cívico y el establecimiento de sentimientos de un sentido de lugar.
>
> Lo más necesario son estos "terceros lugares" que dan un equilibrio público a la creciente privatización de la vida en el hogar. Los terceros lugares no son más que lugares públicos informales de reunión. La frase "terceros lugares" deriva de considerar nuestros hogares como los "primeros" lugares en nuestras vidas, y nuestro trabajo coloca el "segundo".

#### ¿Cuándo debo visitar el chat?

- Para la colaboración en tiempo real
- Para conocer a los compañeros de su comunidad en un ambiente más social
- Para una conversación menos estructurada, informal (pero aún más o menos sobre el tema)

#### ¿Dónde está el chat?

Hay un enlace para chatear en el pie de cada página, así como en el menú de Stack Exchange (esquina superior izquierda de la página). El chat de este sitio está en:

$ChatUrl

#### ¿Por qué necesito 20 rep para hablar en un chat?

Tu reputación en el chat es la misma que tu reputación en el sitio principal.

Siempre puedes entrar en salas de chat y escuchar sin representante en absoluto.

No podemos permitir la participación anónima en el chat, por lo que necesitamos un poco de reputación del sitio padre para garantizar que el chat esté reservado para miembros activos y comprometidos de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

**edit questions and answers** - traducido

*Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately*

```
### What is edit questions and answers?

We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit *anything* in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts—*anyone's posts!*

### When should I edit posts?

Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

Some common reasons to edit are:

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
- to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
- to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
- to add related resources or hyperlinks

**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

### How do I edit posts?

The `edit` link is available under each post.

### What happens when I edit a post?

The post will be updated to show the latest editor, as well as the original author. All edits are saved and tracked in a revision history with attribution to each editor. 

The revision history can be viewed by clicking the date and time next to the edited post (e.g. "edited 3 days ago").

Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new attention is brought to something substantial.

### Reviewing suggested edits

In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing [suggested edits][2] (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.

Aside from reviewing suggested edits, the [low quality posts][3] queue is also made available. This queue contains posts which were deemed of low quality by the system. Users are charged with the task of editing to improve their formatting and content, recommending deletion if it doesn't belong on our site, or marking that it is an acceptable post.

  [1]: /help/privileges/community-wiki
  [2]: /review/suggested-edits
  [3]: /review/low-quality-posts
```

**----------------------------------**

**editar preguntas y respuestas**

*Las ediciones a cualquier pregunta o respuesta se reflejan automáticamente*

---

#### ¿Qué es la edición de preguntas y respuestas?

Creemos en el poder de que la comunidad edite. Esto quiere decir que cuando has conseguido suficiente reputación, confiamos en ti para editar *cualquier cosa* en el sistema sin que ello deba ser revisado por otras personas. No solamente tus publicaciones, sino *¡las de todo el mundo!*

#### ¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?

Siempre que veas que puedes mejorar una publicación y te apetezca. ¡Fomentamos la edición!

Algunas razones comunes para editar son:

- para corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía
- para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla
- para corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece
- para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados

**No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales**: intenta mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo todos los problemas que encuentres.

#### ¿Cómo edito las publicaciones?

El enlace `edit` está disponible debajo de cada publicación.

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando edito una publicación?

La publicación se actualizará mostrando el último editor, así como su autor original. Todas las ediciones se guardan y monitorizan en un historial de revisiones atribuidas a cada editor.

El historial de revisiones se puede ver apretando en la fecha y hora al lado de la publicación editada (por ejemplo: "editado hace 3 días").

La edición de una publicación la lanza a la parte más alta de la página inicial. Por favor, tenlo en cuenta y haz que tus ediciones tengan sentido, para que la atención que genere sea a algo sustancial.

#### Revisar las ediciones sugeridas

Además, los usuarios con este nivel de privilegios también pueden empezar revisando las [ediciones sugeridas](/review/suggested-edits) (que previamente habrías tenido que sugerir). Estas ediciones permanecen en un estado  pendiente hasta que reciben suficientes votos para o bien aprobarlas y que se materialice o bien se descarte la edición. Dos votos en uno de los sentidos finalizan la acción, excepto en Stack Overflow donde hacen falta tres.

Además de revisar las ediciones sugeridas, también pasa a estar disponible la cola de [publicaciones de baja calidad](/review/low-quality-posts). Esta cola contiene publicaciones consideradas de baja cualidad por parte de nuestro sistema. Los usuarios están encargados de editar para mejorar su formato y contenido, recomendar su eliminación si no pertenece a nuestro sitio o marcarlas como una publicación aceptable.

Comment: Nótese que el texto original contiene el enlace `[1]: /help/privileges/community-wiki` si bien no hay ningún `[1]`.