# ¿A dónde habría que reportar un error de escritura o traducción dentro del sitio?

Tags: soporte, traducciones

Navegando en varias páginas de SO Español, noté que hay errores de traducción o escritura. Por ejemplo

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

> Los usuarios **asentadosson** aquellos que han

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

> •  para clarificar el sentido de una **publciación** sin cambiarla

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

> Por tu **primer** edición de wiki de etiqueta, obtienes la medalla Editor de etiquetas:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

> Finalmente, como un miembro de la comunidad con reputación alta, tus opiniones probablemente conlleven un peso **significatico**

**¿A dónde hay que reportarlos?**

Comment:  culpable de las últimas 2

Comment: Suele pasar ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las traducciones de privilegios fueron realizadas por la comunidad en un esfuerzo conjunto. Esto fue llevado a cabo en la pregunta:

#### [¿Queréis ayudar a traducir los privilegios? ¡Hacedlo aquí!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/998/127)

Cada respuesta es un wiki de comunidad que se puede editar. Al corregirla, deberías eliminar el texto `::Actualizado::` que está al comienzo.

Comment: Y en el caso de un error como los que reporte，que son pequeños? Aviso al traductor? O como seria?

Comment: No hay _**un**_ editor, fueron traducidas por el primero que quería, y luego editadas por todos los que quisieron. En caso de que necesites una segunda opinión, se puede dejar un comentario a alguno(s) de los que participaron en la edición. Pero viendo el tipo de correcciones que estás proponiendo, no creo que haga falta avisar a nadie.

Comment: Perfeto. Gracias.