# ¿Si una respuesta se convierte en wiki de la comunidad recibe recompensa?

Tags: soporte, wiki-de-comunidad, recompensas

Me preguntaba si al marcar una respuesta como wiki de la comunidad en una pregunta con [recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), esta respuesta recibe la recompensa aun cuando el centro de ayuda dice que no recibe puntaje por votos a favor.

[image: pantallazo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, recibe recompensa y esos puntos van a parar a la persona que publicó la respuesta.

De la respuesta canónica [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/209901), es decir, *¿Cómo funciona el sistema de recompensas?*:

> #### ¿Cómo afecta wiki de comunidad a las recompensas?
>
> Las recompensas no se ven afectadas por el modo de wiki de comunidad. Cuando entregas una recompensa a una respuesta marcada como wiki de comunidad, el bonus de reputación se entrega al usuario que publicó la versión original de la respuesta.

También en [¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/83):

> - Las recompensas otorgadas a respuestas marcadas como wiki otorgan reputación de la manera habitual.