# ¿Qué hacer en caso de que el OP publica en comentarios o en la pregunta misma la solución que encontró a su pregunta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia

En ocasiones un usuario publica una pregunta que es bien recibida (votos positivos) y luego vuelve para compartir la solución que ha encontrado en comentarios

¿Qué hacer en estos casos, en particular cuando la pregunta no tiene ninguna respuesta?

Ejemplos:

- [¿Como resolver numéricamente ecuaciones de la forma y^3 + (a + bx^2)*y^2 = cx^2 donde las variables son x e y?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40392/como-resolver-num%C3%A9ricamente-ecuaciones-de-la-forma-y3-a-bx2y2-cx2/51364#51364)

[image]

- [Search and kill process, and start new process on bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241586/search-and-kill-process-and-start-new-process-on-bash-script/) (En el sitio en inglés {chapó a [fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui)})

---

No sólo ocurre que publiquen la respuesta en los comentarios, también ocurre que el OP edita la pregunta para agregar la respuesta, como en el siguiente caso:

[Cómo reemplazar con str_replace() si tengo un array con valores contenidos en otros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50262/)

Comment: Es la primera vez que veo esa situación. Lo que si he visto es que comentan que ya lo solucionaron.

Comment: Yo lo he visto varias veces, pero no recuerdo de otras aquí en SOes. Supongo que ocurre con mayor frecuenta en etiquetas frecuentadas por quienes desarrollan funciones/scripts de usuario. Es la primera vez que pregunto sobre que hacer. Creo que es mas frecuente que publiquen la solución en la pregunta,... si encuentro un caso así lo agregaré.

Answer (score 4):

1. Sugiérele al OP que publique su solución como respuesta.

   - Si el usuario es nuevo, incluye [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
2. Espera unos días, digamos una semana.

   - Para esto te puede servir marcar como favorita la pregunta o usar alguna aplicación de recordatorios como el [complemento de Google Inbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inbox-by-gmail/gkljgfmjocfalijkgoogmfffkhmkbgol) en conjunto con la función de posponer.
3. Si el OP no lleva acción alguna, copia los comentarios a una respuesta y publícala

   - Si estas familiarizado con el tema, dale formato apropiado y enriquece la respuesta
   - Si no vas a agregar nada, considera publicarla como [Wiki de Comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-wiki-de-comunidad), esto seguramente será bien recibido por la comunidad y algunos se animaría a enriquecer la respuesta.
4. En el caso que la respuesta fue agregada a la pregunta, edita la pregunta para eliminar la respuesta y en el resumen de los cambios, menciona que esta fue publicada como respuesta.

Comment: El problema sería darle un seguimiento puntual a esa pregunta para saber si ya la respondió, o en su caso responderla. No estoy seguro que todos los usuarios tengan ese nivel de compromiso, ya que si la pregunta ya no aparece entre las más recientes ya no parece ser revelvante y queda en el olvido. Y suponiendo que la pregunta se le agrega su respuesta seguirá apareciendo meses después lanzada por el usuario Comunidad. Pero el punto lo capto y me parece perfecto, ingresar a [es.so] y ver que tenga respuestas válidas, aunque no estén aceptadas.

Comment: En la redacción lo he puesto como si un sólo usuario fuera a hacer los tres pasos, pero bien puede hacerse de forma colectiva, lo cual es viable si varios asumimos el compromiso de revisar las preguntas sin respuesta, y no es tan cándido, pues está a sólo un clic de distancia, jeje

Comment: @Flxtr bien visto. [Me pasó](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42297253/1983854)  hace poco y lo que hice fue lo siguiente: - primero le comenté al OP en comentarios que [puede responder su propia pregunta](/help/self-answer); como pocas veces funciona esto, me la puse en favoritos; a los dos días o así volví y vi que no había hecho nada, por lo que la publiqué como respuesta en modo wiki. Parece que funcionó, pues el OP la acabó aceptando. Resumiendo: si la pones en favoritos puedes volver a ella, pero requiere recordarlo y es un poco pesado.

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu experiencia. Incorporé el enlace al artículo de ayuda a la respuesta y el caso a la pregunta.

Comment: @Rubén Que se debe hacer con una pregunta que fué cerrada y que el OP editó su respuesta e incluyó la respuesta (Al estar cerrada necesita votos de reapertura para que se pueda incluir respuestas). Revisar: [¿Cómo puedo colocar propiedades diferentes de un mismo artículo dentro de un select?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56523/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-colocar-propiedades-diferentes-de-un-mismo-art%C3%ADculo-dentro-de-un-sel)

Comment: @Davlio: Me parece que se trata de un caso marginal por lo que debería valorarse de forma individual, en otras palabras, si te parece que ese trata de un hilo valioso, considera publicar una pregunta específica en [meta] para que la comunidad opine sobre el caso particular.

Comment: @Rubén lo mejor es darlo por cerrado, concuerdo con la opinión encontrada en el chat.

Answer (score 3):

Un comentario **no es una respuesta** por lo que la pregunta no tiene respuesta.

Lo ideal es:

- Dejar un comentario indicando al autor del comentario que lo publique como respuesta. Si lo hace, solucionado.
- En caso de dejar pasar un tiempo indeterminado y vemos que no se publica como respuesta uno mismo es libre de publicarlo como tal y seria importante dejar un enlace al comentario original. Entonces la pregunta ya tiene respuesta, solucionado.

Este es el proceso ideal. Siempre hay excepciones =P.

Comment: El problema con los comentarios es que son transitorios, así que hay un alto riesgo que el enlace a los mismos se rompa. Por lo demás, de acuerdo (nuestras respuestas, incluyendo la de Jorgesys, coinciden en un ~ 80% pero es mejor la respuesta de otro a una auto-respuesta).

Comment: Tu respuesta como indicas es muy parecido y completamente correcta. he querido ponerla para finiquitar el tema, básicamente. Puedes aceptar la tuya sin problema, la veo 100% correcta igualmente :)

Answer (score 1):

Algunos usuarios sugieren en los comentarios soluciones, algunos son enlaces, en ocasiones proponen algo que al final termina siendo solución, sin embargo esto solo queda definido como comentario, lo correcto es agregar una respuesta para que sea de valor para los usuarios de la comunidad.

Se puede sugerir a el usuario que agrego el comentario que

- Lo agregue como respuesta.
- En otro caso un usuario puede agregarla como respuesta y desarrollarla un poco más.

Comment: De todos modos fíjate que en la pregunta se está refiriendo al caso específico en que el propio OP publica su respuesta en los comentarios. Yo creo que, además de lo que comentas, es siempre interesante pasarles un enlace a la página [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](/help/self-answer)

Comment: Una respuesta no va en comentarios.

Comment: Ya, ya lo sé. Eso es precisamente lo que estoy diciendo, que se le puede sugerir que lo mueva a una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con [esta respuesta de Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1455/78), de hecho, iba a crear una pregunta muy similar a la tuya.

Creo que esto ayudaría a mejorar el asunto con los números visualizados en el sitio Area51, tal como se escribe en una pregunta *de la cual no tengo el enlace a la mano.*

Así lo hice hasta el momento con [una sola pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/52278/78).

Lo ideal con esta opción es que no se busque reputación *(a menos que seas la misma persona que haya creado/sugerido la respuesta en un comentario)* sino que se mejoren las [estadísticas del sitio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stackoverflow-in-spanish) *(en cuanto al porcentaje de respuestas)*.

Claro está, cuando el comentario efectivamente cumpla con las condiciones de ser una respuesta.