# ¿Qué hacer con una pregunta que el mismo usuario que la preguntó la contesta pero no agrega su solución como respuesta?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales

Viendo las preguntas sin responder en Stack Overflow en español vi [una sobre java EE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17659/puedo-cargar-un-interceptor-desde-una-librer%C3%ADa) donde el mismo usuario que la preguntó la contestó, pero no agrega la respuesta en la pregunta.

¿Qué se podría hacer en este caso?

1. Dejar la pregunta así.
2. Voto negativo

Comment: Te equivocas con esa pregunta. El que responde la pregunta no es el mismo que la hizo, sino otro usuario que lamentablemente eliminó su cuenta,con lo que tanto sus comentarios como respuestas (esto último no estoy seguro pero creo que también) han sido eliminados del sistema. De todas maneras, no deberías votar negativamente una pregunta solo porque no se ha añadido respuesta.

Comment: Si, @pikoh, las respuestas también. Gilberto, esta pregunta me recuerda a [esta otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1455/15855) y la respuesta que da Rubén me parece adecuada. Si consideras que el comentario del usuario borrado es convertible a respuesta, puedes hacerlo siguiendo [answer]. Aunque es una publicacion antigua y el que preguntó lleva tiempo sin conectarse al sitio, puede ser de utilidad para futuros users. Un saludo

Answer (score 5):

La cosa no fue así: la pregunta la formuló [Ricardo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/3488/ricardo) y [el comentario que mencionas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17659/puedo-cargar-un-interceptor-desde-una-librer%C3%ADa/126500#comment28925_17659) lo dejó el usuario 227, que era Luiggi Mendoza y que hace poco borró su cuenta :(

La cuestión aquí es que has detectado un contenido útil que puede quedarse perdido entre los comentarios. Para evitar esto, lo que he hecho, y que sugiero que hagas si te vuelves a encontrar en esta tesitura, es crear una [respuesta wiki de comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/126500/83) con ese contenido.

**¿Por qué convertirlo en respuesta?**

Porque los comentarios son elementos de segunda clase, no pueden editarse, no lucen tanto.

**¿Por qué en modo wiki de comunidad?**

Porque esto permite, de hecho incentiva, que se mejore entre todos. Además, deja claro que poner la respuesta no es un intento de ganar reputación.

Véase [¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/83)