# Se permite crear Tutoriales en Stack Overflow sin necesidad de utilizar la opción auto responder

Tags: discusión, temática

Resulta que cuando busco información de diferentes fuentes, elaboro pequeños "prototipos" funcionales, pero me gustaría publicarlos en la comunidad como "tutoriales" en la sección donde se hacen las preguntas sin la necesidad de usar la opción de auto responder a mi pregunta.

¿Se permite, sí o no?

Comment: ¿ Cual es el *inconveniente* de publicarlo como pregunta/respuesta ? La marcas como [wiki de comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%c3%a9-es-una-publicaci%c3%b3n-wiki-de-comunidad), y es facil de encontrar por futuros usuarios, sin necesidad de *sección* separada.

Comment: Tutoriales mejor que sean en tu blog. No hay que romper el propósito princial del sitio, que es sobre preguntas y respuestas. Pienso que lo que más se acerca a lo que comentas sería la nueva característica disponible en el sitio en Inglés, *Documentation*.

Answer (score 2):

En síntesis, el modelo del sitio principal "no permite"<sup>1</sup> publicar la solución en la pregunta, la solución se publica como respuesta.

Las preguntas deben seguir los lineamientos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y las respuestas o soluciones deben seguir los lineamientos de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

El artículo de ayuda [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) indica que uno puede responder su propia pregunta, como se ha mencionado en otras publicaciones, por respeto a la comunidad si de antemano se conoce la respuesta a la pregunta que se desea publicar deben publicarse de forma simultánea.

Cabe mencionar que publicar un buen tutorial en forma de pregunta/respuesta no es sencillo por un lado porque cada elemento, pregunta y respuesta, se deben votar por separado.

> <sup>1</sup>: El modelo de Stack Overflow en español, se basa en el modelo de los sitios de la red de Stack Exchange, pero algunas cosas podrían ser diferentes. El modelo incluye como elemento fundamental el que la comunidad es la que en primera instancia modera el sitio a través de los votos positivos/negativos y a través de los privilegios que se ganan con base en la reputación o bien por haber sido designado como moderador diamantado. La moderación incluye la edición del contenido, así que si tu publicación resulta interesante, seguramente algún miembro "la arreglará", si no resulta interesante, seguramente será cerrada y eventualmente eliminada, y si hay opiniones divididas, seguramente habrán discusiones al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se permiten, pero no lo recomiendo. Y principalmente por respeto a la gente que se toma su tiempo para responder.

La idea es que haces una pregunta, la dejas abierta un tiempo, alguien le dedica tiempo a contestarla para ver que al OP publicó la respuesta que la resuelve.

Lo ideal es hacer la pregunta y contestarla en el mismo momento. Si alguien tiene tiempo para presentar una respuesta alternativa, por lo menos ya sabe que la pregunta está contesta y se beneficia la comunidad.

Comment: Me parece confuso la forma en la que está expresada la respuesta, creo que el último párrafo debería ir primero y sobre el primero según entiendo no se debe publicar la solución en la misma pregunta, así que no debería permitir publicar tutoriales usando sólo la pregunta.