# ¿Qué hago con una traducción que marqué como wiki de comunidad?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, wiki-de-comunidad

Hace algunos dias [A. Cedano publicó una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90081/por-qu%C3%A9-pdo-recibe-par%C3%A1metros-sin-los-dos-puntos-al-usar-consultas-preparadas/90114) en la cual fedorqui indicó que ya existía una respuesta igualmente muy buena en el sitio en inglés. Me di a la tarea de traducirla (al menos la parte realmente importante). La respuesta fue aceptada y ha recibido varios votos.

Ya que yo no sabía la respuesta técnica (solo lo intuia), marqué la pregunta como wiki de comunidad, porque pensé que no era justo recibir crédito (reputación) solo por la intuición y porque sé algo de inglés (y además fue fedorqui quien tenia el link de la respuesta).

Dias despues de esta respuesta, vi la pregunta de Meta [¿Qué es una wiki de comunidad?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-wiki-de-comunidad), y alli dice explícitamente que si se hace una traducción del sitio en ingles, **no** debe marcarse como wiki de comunidad, por las razones que no repetire acá.

Realmente no hay problema si recibo o no esa reputación, pero para que quede registrado para el futuro, ¿qué debo hacer con esta respuesta? ¿Pedir a un moderador que la convierta en respuesta normal? o ¿dejarla así como esta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

No te preocupes demasiado, puedes dejarla así como está.

## Explicación

Digamos que ya has aprendido un poco más de cómo quiere la comunidad que se usen los wikis de comunidad. Deja que alguien más haga el reporte. Si procede o no, no está en tus manos y no debe depender que el OP haga el reporte.

El revertir el estado de wiki de comunidad a una publicación está a juicio de los moderadores de la comunidad. En mi opinión, deberías dejar que pasen las elecciones, que los moderadores electos revisen lo que haya por hacer y que ejerzan su rol de liderazgo convocando a la comunidad hacia los temas que requieren la atención de los que participamos en Meta. Uno de ellos podría ser el revisar todos los wikis de comunidad.

## Relacionado

- [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2974/289691)